# Drawing a circle on a non xy-plane with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, circles

Say I'm drawing a 3D picture. Now I would like to draw a circle, perspectively correct, on the yz-plane, but TikZ does not seem to be capable of this. All one can do is drawing circles on the xy-plane. Also ellipses, which take two radii, are drawn on the xy-plane only. I know I can use `rotate` to rotate ellipses, but this is not really straightforward, as it involves calculating rotation angles and radii.

So is there anyway to tell `TikZ` to draw on a certain plane? Or is there any other fancy package fo it?

Just for illustration:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) -- (0,4,4) -- (0,0,4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,2,2) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Obviousely, I would like to draw the circle in the yz-plane. This would look like an ellipse, fitting perfectly in the yz-plane square (which, due to perspective looks like a parallelogram).

Comment: You might find my answer to this question of some use: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz/31606#31606

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Wow, worked perfectly. Care to write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything more that I would say than is already in that answer and it's the first part of that answer too so there's not a load of extra stuff to wade through to find it (except for my ... curious ... style).  So it feels a bit more like a candidate for closing as duplicate (there are already two votes for such).  Would you be deeply offended if I suggested that instead?

Comment: Of course not. I have the answer I needed, and that's what counts. I think I'll accept Altermundus answer then.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Two examples of what you can draw with the 3d library. The first on has been modified because something was wrong with shade colour.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     [x={(-0.2cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, 
     scale=3,
     fill opacity=0.80,
     color={gray},bottom color=white,top color=black]

 \tikzset{zxplane/.style={canvas is zx plane at y=#1,very thin}}
 \tikzset{yxplane/.style={canvas is yx plane at z=#1,very thin}}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=-1]
   \shade[draw] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
   \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm] ;
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[zxplane=-1]
       \shade[draw] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[zxplane=1]
   \shade[draw] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=1]
       \shade[draw] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
     \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture} 



 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
     \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
     \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
   \end{scope}

   \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
     \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
     \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
   \end{scope}

   \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
     \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
     \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
   \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this terrific example. However, I am not able to figure where the gray color shading in the first picture is coming from? I changed all the colors to various other colors so I can correlate the code with the lines, and nothing I seem produces a color other than gray for the shading. Let me know if you think I should post a question, or did I miss something obvious.

Comment: @Peter You are right, I need to modify the example. I created this example before pgf 2.1 and now it's necessary to use something like ` \path[bottom color=white,top color=black,draw] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);`.

Comment: @Peter  I modified the example, now you can modify the color or add shading only for the circle.

Comment: I've never heard of the 3D library before, and now I see that it is in my TikZ/PGF system.  Wow!  I need to learn what it does.

Comment: Did a bit of investigating.  I think it's worth pointing out that the 3D library sets up some coordinate transformations and these apply to circles even when the radii are specified as dimensions.  So the `x=...,y=...,z=...` apply to `circle[radius=2cm]` *because* the values of the x,y,z vectors are used to define a transformation.

Comment: @Andrew it's avery little library without documentation `pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary3d.code.tex,v 1.1 2008/01/09`. I put an example here : `http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/annotated-3d-box/`. I have only one example  from T. Tantau with magnetic and electric fields.

Comment: @Andrew In the sources of the documentation, you can find `Three Dimensional Drawing Library`but this part of the manual is not compiled in the final pdf.

Comment: Thanks.  I've found the code and had a look.  It doesn't do a lot, that's true, but what it does is quite neat.

Comment: One reason I'm particularly interested in this is that I've been working on a 3D library that can do a bit more than just convert 3D coordinates to 2D ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the infos, I didn't know either of the 3D library, thats true _deep magic_. Also, it's even easier than Andrew Stacey's approach in the other question. Huzzah!

Answer (score 14):

[`pst-3dplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot) forms part of the [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) suite and provides macros to print regular 2D stuff on planes in 3D (amongst other things).

Here is a minimal example the plots a circle on the 3 orthogonal planes: `xy`, `xz` and `yz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psset{linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=black!50,unit=2cm}%
  \pstThreeDLine(-2,0,0)(2,0,0)% x-axis
  \pstThreeDLine(0,-2,0)(0,2,0)% y-axis
  \pstThreeDLine(0,0,-2)(0,0,2)% z-axis

  \psset{linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black} 
  \pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,0){%
    \pscircle[linestyle=solid](0,0){2cm}%
    \rput{90}(-2.5cm,2.5cm){XY-plane}%
  }
  \pstPlanePut[plane=xz](0,0,0){%
    \pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2cm}%
    \rput{0}(-2.5cm,2.5cm){\reflectbox{XZ-plane}}%
  }
  \pstPlanePut[plane=yz](0,0,0){%
    \pscircle[linestyle=dotted](0,0){2cm}%
    \rput{0}(-2.5cm,2.5cm){YZ-plane}%
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The only reason for including [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) was for `\reflectbox`.

Perspective of the object(s) can be modified using different values for `Alpha` or `Beta` (two components of spherical coordinates) or by using rotation angles `\RotX`, `\RotY` and `\RotZ`. See the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-3dplot/pst-3dplot-doc.pdf) for some more examples.