# Drawing circle within 3d pgfplot axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I want to draw a circle at the end of a semi-cylinder.
However I was not able to change the orientation (plane) for this circle. I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334640/drawing-circles-on-a-3d-plane) that suggests to use `[x={(0,0, 1)}]` but it does not seem to work inside of pgfplots `axis` environment. I tried to refer to the correct coordinate system `axis cs:` for the transformation but that also did not help.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\ycenter}{1}
\newcommand{\zcenter}{1}
\newcommand{\myradius}{1}

\newcommand{\myxmax}{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=\myxmax]
        \addplot3[
            domain y = \ycenter-\myradius:\ycenter+\myradius,
            surf,
        ]
        {-sqrt(\myradius^2 - (y-\ycenter)^2) + \zcenter};

        % center of the circle at the right end of semicylinder
        \node at (\myxmax, \ycenter, \zcenter) {O};

        % this circle is not oriented correctly
        \draw[red] (\myxmax, \ycenter, \zcenter) circle (1);
        % sadly this does not help
        \draw[green] (\myxmax, \ycenter, \zcenter) [x={(0,0,1)}] circle (1);
        % neither does this
        \draw[black] (1, 0, 0) [x={(axis cs: 0,0,1)}] circle (1);


    \end{axis}
    % this does not refer to the correct coordinate system
    \draw[blue] (\myxmax, \ycenter, \zcenter) circle (1);
    \draw[blue] (\myxmax, \ycenter, \zcenter) [x={(0,0,1)}] circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

Ty for any help,

Franz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one simple way to plot the circle(makes many small curves) and an other more complicated way to draw a real circle

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, calc}
\newcommand{\ycenter}{1}
\newcommand{\zcenter}{1}
\newcommand{\myradius}{1}
\newcommand{\myxmax}{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=\myxmax]
\addplot3[domain=-\myxmax:\myxmax, domain y=\ycenter-\myradius:\ycenter+\myradius, surf,
] {-sqrt(\myradius^2 - (y-\ycenter)^2) + \zcenter};
\addplot3[ultra thick, domain=0:360, variable=t, smooth] (\myxmax,{\ycenter+\myradius*cos(t)},{\zcenter+\myradius*sin(t)});
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\myxmax]
\draw[red, thick] let \p1=(\myradius,0), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (\ycenter,\zcenter) circle[radius=\n1];
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D surface with a circle at the end]

Comment: Very nice ty. Totally unrelated but I didn't find an answer in the help center. Is there a standard way to include pdf's from MWEs into questions or answers? Is there a build in tex compiler on this site?

Comment: There is no standard way and also not any way to include a pdf. There is no tex compiler on this site. The easiest way is to compile locally or online(e.g. https://www.overleaf.com) and take a screenshot to include.

Comment: OK ty. That what I also did.

Comment: Can you quickly comment on why my approaches did not work?

Comment: I have trouble to see how you could believe that it would work. -wrong center, wrong coordinate system. `axis cs:` does nothing, as it is default coordinate system. The red circle is correct, but oriented in the xy plane. I will happily explain further - let me know what/which you do not understand.