# How can I add a circle along the planes?

Tags: graphics, 3d

[image]

Hello! I was wondering how I can add a circle (x-1.5)^2+(y-1.5)^2=1.5^2 as shown in red. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=10cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [tdplot_main_coords,
            cube/.style={very thick,black},
            axis/.style={->,blue,thick}]

    %draw the axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[anchor=west]{$z$};
 
    %draw the top and bottom of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (3,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[cube] (0,0,3) -- (0,3,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (3,0,3) -- cycle;
    
    %draw the edges of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
    \draw[cube] (0,3,0) -- (0,3,3);
    \draw[cube] (3,0,0) -- (3,0,3);
    \draw[cube] (3,3,0) -- (3,3,3);

        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: [Drawing a circle on a non xy-plane with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32077/123129)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the following line of code

```
            \draw[thick, red] (1.5, 1.5, 0)  circle (1.5);
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=10cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        
        
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [tdplot_main_coords,
            cube/.style={very thick,black},
            axis/.style={->,blue,thick}]
            
            %the circle
            \draw[thick, red] (1.5, 1.5, 0)  circle (1.5);

            %draw the axes
            \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
            \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
            \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[anchor=west]{$z$};
            
            %draw the top and bottom of the cube
            \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (3,0,0) -- cycle;
            \draw[cube] (0,0,3) -- (0,3,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (3,0,3) -- cycle;
            
            %draw the edges of the cube
            \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
            \draw[cube] (0,3,0) -- (0,3,3);
            \draw[cube] (3,0,0) -- (3,0,3);
            \draw[cube] (3,3,0) -- (3,3,3);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: For the circles in the other planes, you can use `\draw[thick, blue, canvas is yz plane at x=0] (1.5,1.5) circle (1.5);` and `\draw[thick, green, canvas is xz plane at y=0] (1.5,1.5) circle (1.5);`. (see also [Drawing a circle on a non xy-plane with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32077/123129))