# Calculating moon phase for LaTeX calendar

Tags: calendar

How can I calculate the moon phase for LaTeX calendar?

My start point is D.E.Knuth's algorithm to calculate Easter is applied here https://texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/

The number E is the epact, which specifies when a full moon occurs. However, I don't know how to access the variable \l_easter_E_int

If I could access E, then full moon would happen around 29 days after E.

The code

```
  Easter=-3, % Maundy Thursday
  Easter=-2, % Good Friday
  Easter,    % Easter Sunday
  Easter=1,  % Easter Monday
  Easter=39, % Feast of the Ascension
  Easter=49, % Pentecost
  Easter=50, % Whit Monday
```

Seems to be an easy way to state days with respect to "Easter". I don't know how this command works.

But instead of Easter=1, Easter=29,

How can I make the reference Epach=1, Epach=29, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Knuth's algorithm is for the calculation of *Easter Sunday*. For moon phase calculations, other, much more precise algorithms exist. Run a google search for "moon phase calculator" to learn about some of them.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. After 1 hour of search, I have not found any LaTeX calendar example with automatically calculated moon phases. Also, my calendar will in every casel contain Knuth's algorithm which already calculates a full moon occurence \l_easter_E_int.

Comment: What about using a Lua script via LuaLaTeX?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34785/how-to-typeset-moon-phase-symbols for how to typeset the phase, once it is calculated.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes OK, I know this. But how can I typeset the Easter, once it is calculated?

Comment: I'm not sure your exact meaning.  In the Western world, Easter falls on the first Sunday after the first full moon after the vernal equinox.  Therefore, Easter will always be between 1 and 7 days after the full moon, depending on the year.

Answer (score 1):

I remember back in the 80s there being a plain TeX macro in a file `phoon.tex` which calculated the phase of the moon, but this appears to have disappeared along with a lot of other ephemera of that era. However, there is another plain TeX macro file, https://ctan.org/pkg/dayofweek which includes a macro which calculates the phase of the moon.

I found this by going to https://ctan.org and entering “moon” into the searchbox. Too bad there's no longer any trace of that old `phoon.tex` file. I'm pretty sure that was the first solution of the problem.