# TikZ: How to draw an isometric drawing in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

In the below image

- top: rectangles
- Bottom: isometric views. How to do it in TikZ?

[image]

Similar result but not correct...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=30]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to put `x={(0.86cm,0.5cm)},y={(-0.86cm,0.5cm)}` into your `tikzpicture` options to get an isometric perspective. If you want to use 3D coordinates, you also have to specify `z={(0cm,1cm)}`, and use three dimensional coordinates (like `\draw (0,0,1) -- (2,1,3)`).

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.

Comment: Tikz now supports `[isometric view]` using the `perspective` tikzlibrary.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like Andrew wrote, 3d is not in the documentation. I updated my answer because I introduced some mistakes and complications. First we need to define the vectors for the xyz system, then with the `3d`library options, we can work in a specific plane.

```
 canvas is xy plane at z=0
```

I design the plane `xy with z=0`, I made a mistake with `yx` because in this case I exchange the vectors `x` and  `y`.

Here a list of the options in 3d

```
coordinate system  xyz cylindrical
coordinate system  xyz spherical

/tikz/cs/longitude/
/tikz/cs/latitude/

 plane origin
 plane x
 plane y

 canvas is plane
 canvas is xy plane at z
 canvas is yx plane at z
 canvas is xz plane at y
 canvas is zx plane at y
 canvas is yz plane at x
 canvas is zy plane at x
```

The code :

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,3d}

 % see the explanation below
 \makeatletter
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
   \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
 }
 \makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [x={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, y={(-0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=2]
  \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) --  (1,0,0);
  \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) --  (0,1,0);    
  \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) --  (0,0,1);    
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
      \draw[blue,shift={(1.5,0)}] (0,0) -- (1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
      \draw[blue,shift={(3,0)}] (0,0) -- (1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{scope}  
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

The code for the option used in my example is

```
  \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}{%
    \tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}}%
  }
```

This is only a shift transformation.

**Update**

As Jake noticed in this answer [grid in 3d](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48774/drawing-axis-grid-in-3d-with-custom-unit-vectors)

> The implementation of canvas is xy plane at z in
>   tikzlibrary3d.code.tex is incorrect, it merely sets a coordinate
>   shift, but doesn't activate the full transformation code necessary.
>   You can redefine the key correctly within your document:

```
 \makeatletter
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
   \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
 }
 \makeatother
```

I forgot this and it is why I use `yx`instead of `xy` in my first attempt.

[image]

Comment: @Jake Yes you are right, I forgot to modify my example

Comment: Given that the `3d` library is not (yet, as I understand it) documented, I think it worth highlighting its use here particularly as it makes life so easy for this.  (Also worth pointing out that there are lots of other examples on this site of its use so its lack of documentation is partially made up for here.)

Comment: Sadly, I can't upvote again ... excellent additions - Thanks!

Comment: To obtain values with good precision, you may use `x={({cos(30)*1cm},{sin(30)*1cm})},y={({cos(150)*1cm},{sin(150)*1cm})},z={(0,1cm)}`

Comment: @PolGab yes you are right, I'm influenced by the data of PGF `(-3.85mm,-3.85mm)` for the `z` vector. Very strange value, `sqrt(2)/4` seems to be more natural.

Comment: Chapter 40 of the pgf manual now covers the 3d library.

Answer (score 18):

As @Jake pointed out in a comment, you can specify the coordinate system of your choice as an option of the `tikzpicture` environment. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(-1cm,0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
% coordinate system
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
\draw[-latex] (O) -- +(1, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0,  1, 0) node [left] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0,  0, 1) node [above] {$z$};
% rectangles
\draw (3,-1.5,0) -- (3,1.5,0) -- (5,1.5,0) -- (5,-1.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw (6,-1.5,0) -- (6,1.5,0) -- (8,1.5,0) -- (8,-1.5,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the resulting image; I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of giving the base vectors as a (x,y) tuple
`[y={(-1cm,0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]`,
I prefer to use (angle:length)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(90:1cm)}, y={(0:1cm)}, z={(45:0.7cm)}]
```

This gives you a better understanding of the vector directions.

Comment: Your command gives a totally different axis system. Am I missing something or was that your intention?

Answer (score 3):

As of `pgf` version 3.1.2, the `perspective` library can be used which provides `isometric view` option.  Relevant changelog: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/doc/generic/pgf/CHANGELOG.md#312---2019-04-04-christian-feuersaenger.

This release was in 2019. I suppose texlive 2020 and later would support this.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view]
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node [pos=1.2] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node [pos=1.2] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node [pos=1.2] {$z$};
    
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        \foreach \xshift in {2,4}{%
            \draw[xshift=\xshift cm] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]