# perspective tikz figure 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I want to rotate my figure, like here below:

[image: my required orientation]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{180}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (4,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (4,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: my current orientation]

What can I do to rotate z-coordinate?

Comment: I think you can have a look to the answers provided in  [TikZ: How to draw an isometric drawing in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/tikz-how-to-draw-an-isometric-drawing-in-tikz).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thank you a lot, I set x={(1cm,0cm)}, y={(0cm,-1cm)}, z={(1cm,-1cm)} and it's working.

Comment: better with[x={(1cm,0cm)}, y={(0cm,-1cm)}, z={({sqrt(2)/2},{sqrt(2)/2})}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   thick,
    scale=3,
    x={(0:1cm)},
    y={(270:1cm)},
    z={(315:1cm)}
]
\draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (4,1,0) node[below]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (4,0,0) -- (4,0,1) node[below right]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]