# rotate node in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, 3d

I am trying to draw this 3D shape

[image: arrows on cylinder]

I draw the 4 arrows and the cylinder, but can't rotate the arrows in 3D to put them on the top.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}    
%,rotate around={30:(0,1,1)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[cylinder, draw=white,fill=blue, shape aspect=0.7,rotate=90,minimum height=0.7cm, minimum width=2cm] {hh};
        \node [fill=red,single arrow, draw=none, rotate=90,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=0.7cm]at(0,0) {};
        \node [fill=blue,single arrow, draw=none, rotate=-90,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=0.7cm] at (0,1.5) {};
        \node [fill=red,single arrow, draw=none, rotate=-180,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=0.7cm]at(-0.75,0.7) {};
        \node [fill=blue,single arrow, draw=none, rotate=-360,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=0.7cm] at (0.75,0.7) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `arrows.meta` library

```
\documentclass[border =3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}    
%,rotate around={30:(0,1,1)}
\tikzset{Ultra thick/.style={line width=2.5pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[cylinder, draw=white,fill=blue, shape aspect=0.7,rotate=90,minimum height=0.7cm, minimum width=2cm,aspect=1.5](c) {hh};
   \begin{scope}[white,-{Triangle[angle=45:1pt 2]},inner sep=0.5pt]
        \node(topt) at (c.-5){};
        \node(topl) at (c.50){};
        \node(topc) at ($(c.before top)!0.5!(c.after top)$){};
        \node(topb) at ($(topc)!-1!(topt)$){};
        \node(topr) at ($(topc)!-1!(topl)$){};
        % draw arrows      
        \draw[Ultra thick](topc)--(topt); 
        \draw[Ultra thick](topc)--(topb);
        \draw[Ultra thick](topr)--(topc);
        \draw[Ultra thick](topl)--(topc);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output [added by cfr]:

[image: cylinder and arrows]

Comment: I hope that you do not mind my adding an image to show the output. What is the point of the `hh`? (I know it is in the original code, but it is not in the target picture and it looks rather odd to me. But perhaps I'm missing the significance.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's another version with uses the 3D library and paints a custom arrow.

The code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is used to correct an error in the implementation of `canvas is xy plane at z=`. As far as I know it was first fixed by **Jake** in [TikZ: How to draw an isometric drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/tikz-how-to-draw-an-isometric-drawing-in-tikz/59410#59410).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, 3d}

\makeatletter
    \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]%
    {   \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
        \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
        \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
        \tikz@canvas@is@plane
    }
\makeatother  

\newcommand{\Arrow}[4]%
% start, direction, length, width
{   \fill[white] (#1) -- ++ (#2+90:#4/2) -- ++ (#2:#3-#4) -- ++ (#2+90:#4/2) -- ++ (#2-45:1.414214*#4) -- ++ (#2-135:1.414214*#4) -- ++ (#2+90:#4/2) -- ++ (#2-180:#3-#4) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   xy/.style={canvas is xy plane at z=#1},
    x={(-20:1cm)},
    y={(20:1cm)},
    z={(90:1cm)},
]
    \fill[cyan!50!gray, draw=white] (-135:4) arc (-135:45:4) -- ++ (0,0,2) arc(45:-135:4) -- cycle;
    \fill[cyan!50!gray, draw=white] ($(225:4)+(0,0,2)$) arc (-135:225:4)
        coordinate[pos=0.20] (n1)
        coordinate[pos=0.55] (n2)
        coordinate[pos=0.70] (n3)
        coordinate[pos=0.95] (n4)
     -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}[xy=2]
        \foreach \A in {1,...,4}
        { \Arrow{{\A*90-60-180*mod(\A,2)}:{3.6-3.2*mod(\A,2)}}{\A*90-60+180}{3.2}{0.5}
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What is `\tikzoption`? Don't recall seeing that. Seems to be a noop here as removing it does not seem to change the image.  Also it does not appear to be documented in the TikZ/PGF manual.

Comment: That's a fix for the not properly working `canvas is xy plane at z=`. If you use it unpatched, it draws everything in planar coordinates instead of `xyz` if I recall correctly.

Comment: I can't see any difference in the output with TexLive2013, 2014 and 2015, so perhaps that was patched a while ago. But, furthermore, I don't see any documentation on `\tikzoption`. I assume it just saves settings that are applied to the start of each `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Hmm, probably it works here for some reason, but for instance `\begin{tikzpicture}
[ x={(-10:1cm)},
 y={(200:1cm)},
 z={(90:1cm)},
]
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0] (0,0) rectangle ++ (2,2);
 \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (0,0) rectangle ++ (2,2);
 \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0] (0,0) rectangle ++ (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}` fails miserably.

Comment: Wow, will have to remember this question if I run into that.  BTW, if you have a reference to a question here that provides this fix you should post it in your answer.  The best reference I can find is [TikZ: How to draw an isometric drawing in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59410/4301).

Comment: Hmm, good idea! I just always remember that there was a catch and add it from an old answer of mine.