# tikzkeys not working inside foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-3dplot

As an attempt to solve my [Define a 2D canvas using preexisting points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655422/define-a-2d-canvas-using-preexisting-points), I came across the idea of @andrew swann's answer to [Pass a 3d coordinate via pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108986/pass-a-3d-coordinate-via-pgfkeys) and tried to adapt it.

This is how the 3d coordinates are stored additionally to the 3d coordinate being transformed into 2d coordinates.

```
    % save 3d coordinates of point
    \def\tdcoord #1 at (#2,#3,#4);{\pgfkeys{/tdcoords/#1/.is
    family,/tdcoords/#1,x/.initial=#2,y/.initial=#3,z/.initial=#4}}
```

And while everything works fine and i was able to adapt the canvas just giving points defined with an additional `\tdcoords`, it only works when that call is not in a foreach loop.

The Error messages are

- Undefined controll sequence
- Missing number, treated as zero
- Argument of \pgfmath@dimen@@ has an extra }
- Paragraph ended before \pgfmath@dimen@@ was complete
- Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Anyone have an idea why or how to fix it?

Adapted MWE:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

    % my adaption attempt
    \makeatletter
    \tikzoption{canvasP}[]{\@setPOxy#1}
    \def\@setPOxy #1,#2,#3%
      {\def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#1)}{\GetY(#1)}{\GetZ(#1)}}%
       \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#2)}{\GetY(#2)}{\GetZ(#2)}}%
       \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#3)}{\GetY(#3)}{\GetZ(#3)}}%
       \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
    \makeatother

    % save 3d coordinates of point
    \def\tdcoord #1 at (#2,#3,#4);{\pgfkeys{/tdcoords/#1/.is
    family,/tdcoords/#1,x/.initial=#2,y/.initial=#3,z/.initial=#4}}

    % Get the 3d coordinate components of a point
    \def\GetX(#1){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tdcoords/(#1)/x}}
    \def\GetY(#1){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tdcoords/(#1)/y}}
    \def\GetZ(#1){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tdcoords/(#1)/z}}

    % Define multiple 3d points following tkz-euclide notation
    \newcommand{\tkzDefdPoints}[2][]{
      \foreach \ptx/\pty/\ptz/\name in {#2}{
        \path [#1] (\ptx,\pty,\ptz) coordinate (\name);
        \tdcoord (\name) at (\ptx,\pty,\ptz);
      }
    }

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
      \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[above]{$y$};
      \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[below left]{$z$};

      \tkzDefdPoints{2/2/2/A,2/3/2/B,2/2/3/C,
                     2/2/2/D,2/3/2/E,2/2/3/F}

      \tdcoord (A) at (2,2,2);
      \tdcoord (B) at (2,3,2);
      \tdcoord (C) at (2,2,3);

      \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

      \begin{scope}[canvasP={A,B,C}]
        \draw[red] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1);
      \end{scope}

      % \begin{scope}[canvasP={D,E,F}]
      %   \draw[blue] (0,1) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) -- (1,0);
      % \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Update: While renaming points, I just realized that this might have nothing to do with the foreach statement. Changing the coordinate names to something that is not a single letter, like `\tdcoord (AX) at (2,2,2);` produces the exact same error, even when it is called outside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `\@setPOxy` is not delimited, meaning `canvasP={AA,BB,CC}` will lead to `#3` being `C` and a `C` lost to TeX.
2. You're storing `\ptx` and so on in the value-keys and not the values (this would need `/.initial/.expanded`).
3. The body of a `\foreach` loop is local, all key assignments are lost after the body.

We could solve 1. by using

```
\tikzset{canvasP/.code=\@setPOxy#1\@stop}
\def\@setPOxy #1,#2,#3\@stop
  {\def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#1)}{\GetY(#1)}{\GetZ(#1)}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#2)}{\GetY(#2)}{\GetZ(#2)}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#3)}{\GetY(#3)}{\GetZ(#3)}}%
   \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
```

but since PGFkeys already uses delimited values/arguments we can just use a key directly here:

```
canvasP/.code args={#1,#2,#3}{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#1)}{\GetY(#1)}{\GetZ(#1)}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#2)}{\GetY(#2)}{\GetZ(#2)}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#3)}{\GetY(#3)}{\GetZ(#3)}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
```

The 2. problem won't be one anymore when we're solving 3.

We need to loop over your list without this being inside a group. (We could also do global definitions similar to [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653809/16595) of mine with a similar cause but that's not necessary.

We could also use PGfplots' `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` but that's not necessary either, we can use the `.list` handler of PGFkeys:

```
def dPoints/.style 2 args={%
  @def dPoints/.code args={##1/##2/##3/##4}{%
    \path [#1] (##1,##2,##3) coordinate (##4);
    \tdcoord (##4) at (##1,##2,##3);},
  @def dPoints/.list={#2}
}
```

This sets up a key `@def dPoints` that takes four arguments separated by `/` very similar to your `\foreach` loop but it does not assign it to a macro nor will it be executed inside a group when we use it with `.list`. (Internally, `.list` uses a scoped (i.e. grouped) `\foreach` loop but it does execute everything after the loop.)

The argument `#1` of `def dPoints` isn't optional anymore (but it can be empty) but since we have it, we need to redefine `@def dPoints` everytime we want to use it.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% my adaption attempt
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  canvasP/.code args={#1,#2,#3}{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#1)}{\GetY(#1)}{\GetZ(#1)}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#2)}{\GetY(#2)}{\GetZ(#2)}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{\GetX(#3)}{\GetY(#3)}{\GetZ(#3)}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane},
  def dPoints/.style 2 args={%
    @def dPoints/.code args={##1/##2/##3/##4}{%
      \path [#1] (##1,##2,##3) coordinate (##4);
      \tdcoord (##4) at (##1,##2,##3);},
    @def dPoints/.list={#2}
  }
}
\makeatother

% save 3d coordinates of point
\def\tdcoord #1 at (#2,#3,#4);{\pgfkeys{/tdcoords/#1/.is
family,/tdcoords/#1,x/.initial=#2,y/.initial=#3,z/.initial=#4}}

% Get the 3d coordinate components of a point
\def\GetX(#1){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tdcoords/(#1)/x}}
\def\GetY(#1){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tdcoords/(#1)/y}}
\def\GetZ(#1){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tdcoords/(#1)/z}}

% Define multiple 3d points following tkz-euclide notation
\newcommand{\tkzDefdPoints}[2][]{\tikzset{def dPoints={#1}{#2}}}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[below left]{$z$};

\tkzDefdPoints{2/2/2/A,2/3/2/B,2/2/3/C,
               2/2/2/D,2/3/2/E,2/2/3/F}

\tdcoord (A) at (2,2,2);
\tdcoord (B) at (2,3,2);
\tdcoord (C) at (2,2,3);

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvasP={A,B,C}]
  \draw[red] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1);
\end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[canvasP={D,E,F}]
   \draw[blue] (0,1) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) -- (1,0);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `\foreach` parses list items starting with `(` different, we could define `@def dPoints` so that we can use `\tkzDefdPoints{(2,2,2)/A, (2,3,2)/B, (2,2,3)/C, (2,2,2)/D,(2,3,2)/E, (2,2,3)/F}`. It probably is still a good idea to `.expanded` all values for `x`, `y` and `z` anyway. On another note: Nodes and coordinates are declared global by PGF/TikZ, so that one an reference a coordinate defined inside a scope (or even another picture). Unless you want to use `\tkzDefdPoints` inside a group (or a more complex `\foreach` loop) I wouldn't bother with it, though.

Comment: Having said that, I'd approach this problem very different. PGFkeys might not be the optimal tool to save these coordinates (after all, PGF doesn't use it either).

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! Indeed solved both of my problems. It will take me a while to understand everything you dropped completely.

Two things: I would be interested in a pointer on how you would solve it differently. And since you also answered my other question, would you drop the short form of your answer there too? I can do it as well, but wouldn't want to take your credit away since your answer here is the complete solution.