# Drawing 3-D shapes

Tags: 3d, shapes

I would like to be easily draw 3-D shapes. I'm finding it difficult. I've got isometric paper, but it's difficult to see where to put the lines. [image: 3-d Shape]
here's my MWE. But is the an easier way to draw shapes like the I've attached. All the measurements need to be on the shapes

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta} % needed for tikz pictures

\begin{document}
    


\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.86cm,0.5cm)},y={(-0.86cm,0.5cm)}, color=black]
    \clip (0,12.5) rectangle (18,12.5);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,25}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,25}
    {
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
        \draw [red ] (4,11) -- (6,13);
        \draw [red ] (4,11) -- (4,15);
        \draw [red ] (4,15) -- (6,17);
        \draw [red] (6,13) -- (6,17);
        \draw [red ] (4,11) -- (10,11);
        \draw [red ] (6,13) -- (12,13);
        \draw [red ] (10,11) -- (12,13);
        \draw [red ] (12,13) -- (12,17);
        \draw [red ] (6,17) -- (12,17);
        %\draw [red, very thick] (12,17) -- (10,15);
        \draw (4,15)-- (10,15); 
        \draw (10,15)-- (12,17);
        \draw (10,15)-- (10,11);
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use 3D coordinates (x, y, z) and use tikz-3dplot to change the viewing angle.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170244/how-to-compute-xslant-and-yslant and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/tikz-how-to-draw-an-isometric-drawing-in-tikz

Comment: Thanks, John, for quick reply.  I've read your suggestions too complicated for me. Could you possible write the code for this example? Then I'll go back and re-read your suggestions.

Comment: Xslant is only needed if you want the text to match the axis planes.  The last link is mo longer needed due to [isometric view].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is more straightforward than those suggested. Just plot it in 3D coordinates as John said i.e. specify (x,y,z).  The coordinates frame indicates that `(x,y)` are the plane of the  page and `z` is "depth". Of course more complex shape will require more work.

If you are working with something more complicated, you may want to check https://tikz.dev/library-perspective#autosec-6021

[image]

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {perspective}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0,0) -- (12,0,0) -- (12,5,0) -- (9,5,0) -- (9,2,0) -- (3,2,0) --(3,5,0) -- (0,5,0) -- cycle;
\draw(0,0,10) -- (12,0,10) -- (12,5,10) -- (9,5,10) -- (9,2,10) -- (3,2,10) --(3,5,10) -- (0,5,10) -- cycle;

\draw (0,0,0)-- (0,0,10);
\draw (12,0,0)-- (12,0,10);
\draw (12,5,0)-- (12,5,10);
\draw (9,5,0)-- (9,5,10);
\draw (9,2,0)-- (9,2,10);
\draw (3,2,0)-- (3,2,10);
\draw (3,5,0)-- (3,5,10);
\draw (0,5,0)-- (0,5,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see by default it isn't the isometric view. It is perspective.

Just add the option `isometric view` such as `\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view]`. of course that will flip the drawing.

Finally, you can toy around with `[3d view = {140}{50}]`

Comment: side note: I may not be aware of how to correctly translate "cavalier perspective", I think it is Oblique projection

Comment: This is what I required a solution that I could play with. Nice and simple to begin with then build up to more advanced things