# Why objects in tikz3d not rotating?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I use `tikz-3dplot` and I expect that `rectangle`, `grid` and similar objects are rotated along with the rest part of the figure. However, they are drawn as if they are in 2D. How do I force a `rectangle` to be drawn in the rotated coodinates?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows, matrix, positioning, decorations.markings, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\def\mycolor{blue}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={->,\mycolor,thick}]

    \def\latnum{8}
    \def\lonnum{8}

    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (\latnum+1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{\huge $lat$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,\lonnum+1,0) node[anchor=north west]{\huge $lon$};

    \fill [orange] (\latnum-2,\lonnum-2,0) rectangle (2,2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because given two points does not determine a rectangle. You have to make clear on which plan the rectangle lies. But before you do so, you will find that it is easier to draw a rectangle with `\draw(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;`.

Comment: I want to draw a filled rectangle, that is why I use `\fill`. How do I do that in 3D?

Comment: I figured that out: `\fill [orange] (\latnum,\lonnum,0) -- ++(-2,0,0) -- ++(0,-2,0) -- ++(2,0,0) -- cycle;` Thank you.

Comment: @Symbol1 Do you want to answer? Or should the OP?

Comment: @cfr Maybe OP. Or you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question.

We expect that the following lines are equivalent. But they are not.

```
\draw[red](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\draw[blue](0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
```

The `rectangle` operator is processed by Ti*k*Z by the following lines (`tikz.code.tex` line 3140-3148

> ```
>   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
>   \tikz@path@lineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\tikz@lasty}}%
>   \tikz@path@lineto{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\tikz@lasty}}%
>   \tikz@path@lineto{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\pgf@ya}}%
>   \pgfpathclose%
>   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\tikz@lasty}}%
> ```

At this level, PGF does not recognize the 3D structure of the graphics, so the rectangle are drawn on the canvas in the 2D-way.

---

---

And here is something really ironic: If you `\usetikzlibrary{3d}` and write

```
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0](0,0)rectangle(1,1)circle(1);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0](0,0)rectangle(1,1)circle(1);
\draw[canvas is zx plane at y=0](0,0)rectangle(1,1)circle(1);
```

Then three circles are drawn correctly and two out of three rectangles are drawn correctly. The incorrect one is the one on the xy-plane.

[image]

This is fixed in [Draw 3D rectangle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108140/draw-3d-rectangle).

Comment: Or one can use `canvas is yx plane at z=0` (notice that it is `y` and then `x`.) This is purely evil.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that I cannot draw a `rectangle` not in `yx` or other 2 planes? I mean is there another way of specifying the plane for a rectangle except those 3 choices?

Comment: Also, I had troubles with `grid`. Can you give some examples of drawing `grid` in 3D? Is the workaround the same as for a rectangle?

Comment: @Antonio If you use `tikz-3dplot` there is a `\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords`. I cannot guarantee that it will work as you desired. But that is the closest thing I can think of.