# Is it possible to draw this configuration in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-3d

I would like to draw this image in Latex.

[image]

Here the arrows inside the ellipse represent dipoles. They are polarized by the magnetic field $B$. $d$ is the distance between the two ellipses.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The purpose of this site is to exchange codes and to ask for help if one is stuck with some LaTeX problem. This usually does not include asking others to translate a screen shot to LaTeX code. However, for newcomers sometimes exceptions are made.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,shapes.geometric,shadows.blur}
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=latex,line join=bevel]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[dashed] (O) -- (-5,0,0);
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=5,transform shape]
     \node[ellipse,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.7,draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=8mm,
     rotate=65] (elliL) at (2,2) {};
     \path (elliL.west) -- (elliL.east) coordinate[pos=0.1] (L1b)
     coordinate[pos=0.3] (L1t) coordinate[pos=0.4] (L2b)
     coordinate[pos=0.6] (L2t) coordinate[pos=0.7] (L3b)
     coordinate[pos=0.9] (L3t);
     \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
     {\draw[thick,-latex] (L\X b) -- (L\X t);}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=-1,transform shape]
     \node[ellipse,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.7,draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=8mm,
     rotate=80] (elliR) at (2,2) {};
     \path (elliR.west) -- (elliR.east) coordinate[pos=0.1] (R1b)
     coordinate[pos=0.3] (R1t) coordinate[pos=0.4] (R2b)
     coordinate[pos=0.6] (R2t) coordinate[pos=0.7] (R3b)
     coordinate[pos=0.9] (R3t);
     \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
     {\draw[thick,-latex] (R\X b) -- (R\X t);}
    \end{scope}
    % this is essentially from the tikz-3dplot manual p. 26-27
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{7}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \node[anchor=south west,color=red] at (P) {$B$};
    \draw[-stealth,color=red,very thick] (O) -- (P);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{1}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{1.5}{0}%
        {\thetavec}{anchor=-110}{$\theta$}
    %
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,blue!70]
    \path (5,2) -- (-1,2) node[midway,below] {$d$}; 
    \pgflowlevelsynccm% not necessary but maybe nicer
    \draw[ultra thick,latex-latex] (5,2) -- (-1,2);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally would not like to depend on others, the more so playing with these codes can be fun. Therefore, I'd like to encourage you to try to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Use `canvas is yx plane at z` instead of `canvas is xy plane at z` (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367560)

Comment: @HenriMenke But I specifically use that plane to indicate that the distance is drawn in this plane, and I do load the fix for this plane. And I use [Jake's fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48774/drawing-axis-grid-in-3d-with-custom-unit-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1)  which seems to be older than [the fix you are referring to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112852/121799). Of course, I could switch to the other plane, but why would I?

Comment: On the bugtracker it was pointed out that the “broken” definition of `xy plane` might actually be deliberate: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/410/

Comment: @HenriMenke I guess that only Till Tantau will be able to clarify this. I do believe that it might be deliberate, but it might be for another reason: this was all written before the tikz-3dplot package was written. So one interpretation is that it was deliberate in order to enable non-orthographic projections, like the one in the OPs screen shot. However, I personally do not like non-orthographic projections, and prefer to share Jake's opinion that the original transformation is not the transformation one should use. Plus the 3d library has no official manual AFAIK.

Comment: @HenriMenke One more thing. If you ever want to transform texts, it would be somewhat unfortunate to have only one option for the projection. Yes, I know you can rectify this by adding further transformations like `rotate=90`, `xscale=-1` and so on. However, I guess there is only one person who will ultimately be able to clarify this. A compromise might be to just add another library to CTAN with a slightly different syntax. Some days I think that this together with [these macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438695/121799) might be useful for some.

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.