# Tikz 3d trimetric view coordinate calculation bug

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, calculations, coordinates, tikz-3d

I'm trying to draw a line in the x-y-plane and circles in the y-z-plane at constant x position.

Problem is, that the circle is far out of position (x-coordinate of center point of the circle is exactly the x-coordinate of the end of the line drawn from origin, but the circle is drawn elsewhere).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,3d}


% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/70600
 \makeatletter
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
     \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
     \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
     \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
     \tikz@canvas@is@plane
 }
 \makeatother 

% Drawing Views
\tikzstyle{trimetric}=[x={(0.926cm,-0.207cm)},y={(0cm,0.837cm)},z={(-0.378cm,-0.507cm)}]


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trimetric, scale=0.1]

        \draw[dashed] (-1, 0,  0) -- (1, 0,  0);
        \draw[dashed] (0, -1,  0) -- (0, 1,  0);
        \draw[dashed] (0, 0,  -1) -- (0, 0,  1);

        \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
        \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(10, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0,  10, 0) node [left] {$y$};
        \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0,  0, 10 ) node [above] {$z$};  


        \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=120.0pt]
            \filldraw circle (.01); % center point
            \draw circle (91.62pt); % radius
        \end{scope}


        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \draw[] (0.0pt, 0.0pt) -- (120.0pt, 120.0pt);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result of tex compilation]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The picture seems to fit with your description.  What do you want to be different?

Comment: x-position of circle `canvas is yz plane at x=120.0pt` doesn't fit the x-position of the end of the line drawn from origin `\draw[] (0.0pt, 0.0pt) -- (120.0pt, 120.0pt)`

Comment: Watch out `cm` and `pt` conversion. `1cm=28.4pt`.

Comment: @ferahfeza circle position `canvas is yz plane at x=120.0pt` is in `pt` and line coordinates `\draw[] (0.0pt, 0.0pt) -- (120.0pt, 120.0pt)` are in `pt` too. If I write it like this `canvas is yz plane at x=120.0pt/28.4` then the circle is drawn correct. But why doesn't Tikz recognize the `pt` scaling?

Comment: @user3116388, I don't know. TiKz experts can answer.

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canvas ... at` uses the internal `\pgfpointxyz`.

The latter function just takes numbers not dimensions; `\pgfpointxyz{a}{b}{c}` gives `a` times the `x`-vector plus `b` times the `y`-vector plus `c` times the `z`-vector.

In particular the units are ignored (rather than throwing an error).
If you write `canvas is yz plane at x=120.0` you get the same result.

You need to specify `x` in your `xyz` system instead.  As your `x`-vector has length `.949cm` you should write

```
x = 120.0*.949/28.4
```

to get the position corresponding to `120pt` since `1cm=28.4pt`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,3d}


% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/70600
 \makeatletter
 \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
     \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
     \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
     \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
     \tikz@canvas@is@plane
 }
 \makeatother 

% Drawing Views
\tikzstyle{trimetric}=[x={(0.926cm,-0.207cm)},y={(0cm,0.837cm)},z={(-0.378cm,-0.507cm)}]


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trimetric, scale=0.1]

        \draw[dashed] (-1, 0,  0) -- (1, 0,  0);
        \draw[dashed] (0, -1,  0) -- (0, 1,  0);
        \draw[dashed] (0, 0,  -1) -- (0, 0,  1);

        \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
        \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(10, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0,  10, 0) node [left] {$y$};
        \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0,  0, 10 ) node [above] {$z$};  

        \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=120.0*.949/28.4]
            \filldraw circle (.01); % center point
            \draw circle (91.62pt); % radius
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \draw[red,->] (0.0pt, 0.0pt) -- (120.0pt,0);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```