# Drawing a node parallel to any of the x, y or z axis in a rotated tridimensionnal picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I want to draw a node exactly parallel to one of the three axes that are rotated. One solution could be to compute the axis angle relative to the horizontal line but I  don't know what is the best way to do it by myself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.5cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=-80,rotate around x=-100,rotate around z=-20]
       \begin{scope}[->]
      \draw(0,0,0)coordinate(O)--+(1,0,0)node[above]{\(x\)};
      \draw(O)--+(0,1,0)node[above]{\(y\)};
      \draw(O)--+(0,0,1)node[left]{\(z\)};
    \end{scope} 

    \node[draw,rectangle,
     rotate= 20, % 20 is not correct
    ] at(1cm,1cm){ \(\parallel x\) axis};

    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the 3d library for that. Just go in a scope `canvas is yz plane at x=0`.

Comment: Can someone please provide some documentation on how to use 3d library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of reading your question, so this answer has two parts. The first picture makes use of the `3d` library and the second one of `calc`. Note that, as of now, there is AFAIK no official documentation of the `3d` library. On the other hand, the key `canvas is xy plane at z=...` etc. is sort of self-explaining.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=-80,rotate around x=-100,rotate around z=-20]
    \begin{scope}[->]
      \draw(0,0,0)coordinate(O)--+(1,0,0)node[above]{\(x\)};
      \draw(O)--+(0,1,0)node[above]{\(y\)};
      \draw(O)--+(0,0,1)node[left]{\(z\)};
    \end{scope} 
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
    \node[draw,rectangle,] at(1,1){ \(\parallel x\) axis};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
    \node[draw,rectangle,] at(1,1){ \(\parallel y\) axis};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0,transform shape]
    \node[draw,rectangle,] at(1,1){ \(\parallel z\) axis};
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}  
%   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=-80,rotate around x=-100,rotate around z=-20]
       \begin{scope}[->]
      \draw(0,0,0)coordinate(O)--+(1,0,0)node[above]{\(x\)};
      \draw(O)--+(0,1,0)node[above]{\(y\)};
      \draw(O)--+(0,0,1)node[left]{\(z\)};
    \end{scope} 
    \path let \p1=(1,0,0),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
    node[draw,rectangle,rotate=\n1+180] at(1cm,1cm){ \(\parallel x\) axis};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.

Comment: ... and now there is also a documentation of the 3d library.

Comment: *g, have fun to add that line to all the other places where I added that line ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow I don't think it is necessary at any other place. The reason to add it here is [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456978/drawing-a-node-parallel-to-any-of-the-x-y-or-z-axis-in-a-rotated-tridimensionna/456992?noredirect=1#comment1149515_456978).

Comment: Ok, agree. But maybe I add another comment with this information to Jake's answer. Good idea @marmot.