# Using beamer tools in tikz, without creating slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to create a tikz picture that makes usage of beamer commands such as `\only<2>`, thereby creating multiple pages and adding lines etc. only in the second page.
I then later on want to include these pages in a presentation.

Currently, I'm doing that by using `\documentclass{beamer}`, and putting the `tikzpicture` inside a `frame`. However, this forces me to finish the presentation in this document: I need to specify frame title, and also footer, and presentation styles.

I would much rather just create the plain pictures here, include them in the other presentation using `\begin{frame}{Foo} \includegraphics{...}\end{frame}`. However, when I do that inside `beamer`, there is unnecessary white space around the tikzpictures. When I don't do it inside `beamer`, I cannot use the `\only`. What should I do?

```
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
\addplot[blue, thick] {x};
\only<2>{\addplot[blue, thick, dashed] {2*x};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is the `beamerarticle` package (part of the beamer class) that allows you to use beamer commands in other classes (such as article), which might be useful here. See page 209 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: @Marijn Using `\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}` allows me to compile everything as `tikz standalone`, but will only show the "last page" of each slide, instead of having several pages. Unfortunately, I cannot find this use caseto be  detailed in the manual.

Comment: How about standalone with `\standaloneframe`s, as e.g. in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168705/121799 ?

Comment: @marmot Better, but pictures are not full scale in the page. Including the pdfs in other presentation will add unnecessary white space.

Comment: Doesn't  tex.stackexchange.com/a/168705/121799  specifically tell you how to include pictures of that sort? (Or are you just looking for an ordinary `\ifnum`? See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459641/121799 for how to use it for drawing certain things only on certain "frames". Sometimes `\ifcase` can be useful.)

Comment: @marmot I understand how to include particular pages only. The problem e.g. in that answer is that there is a lot of white space around the drawings in the `stand-alone-file.pdf`; this white space is then also included when including in the final presentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: `standalone` and `beamer` and `\only` **do** work, just not with `crop` but with `preview`.

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} % for advanced overlay options
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
\addplot[blue, thick] {x};
\only<2>{
\addplot[blue, thick, dashed] {2*x};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This becomes much simpler and better IMHO when using `overlay-beamer-styles`.

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} % for advanced overlay options
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
\addplot[blue, thick] {x};
\addplot[blue, thick, dashed,visible on=<2>] {2*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD ANSWER** (perhaps also useful for some applications, so I keep it for now): Maybe something like this? The role of `beamer`s only is taken by `\ifnum`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
\addplot[blue, thick] {x};
\ifnum\X=2
\addplot[blue, thick, dashed] {2*x};
\fi
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can make much more elaborate examples. Just like in beamer presentations with `\only`, a multipage pdf is generated. Here, however, the figures are cropped at their bounding boxes.

Of course, in a real example you may want to make sure that the coordinates do not jump, e.g. with

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
\addplot[blue, thick] {x};
\ifnum\X=2
\addplot[blue, thick, dashed] {2*x};
\else
\addplot[blue, thick, dashed,opacity=0] {2*x};
\fi
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does what I wanted, albeit I find `\ifnum` to be a lot of overhead. I'd still be interested in a generic solution that directly allows the `beamer` tools such as `\alert<2>` etc, which all can be done with this technique but generate quite messy documents

Comment: @FooBar You're right. I added a proposal that does precisely that. (I first tried using `crop` but this didn't work, yet `preview` does. Whether or not `crop` should work, I don't know.)