# Simple Line in LaTeX Help!

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I'm working in a project for university using LaTeX and I'll make a gif explaning the radians of math. And I really don't know how to make this type of line

[image]

What I have done so far

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}





\begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) circle (10cm);
\draw[line width=0.15cm, blue] (10,0) arc (0:360:10) ;

\draw[-] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[line width=0.15cm,red] (0,0) -- (10,-0);
\node[scale=15.5, red, right, opacity=0.5] at (2,2) {r};

\draw[red][fill] (0,0) circle (0.2cm);
\draw[red][fill] (10,-0) circle (0.2cm);


  \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But you get this type of line in your MWE? What do you want to achieve? The animation?

Comment: yes the frames for the animation, ill uploud my project to mediashare and can you see the result?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/wc4xazt8k4h4t5h/testeAnime.pdf/file

Comment: thats the pdf :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\radians
\def\obj#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pscircle{4}
    \psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
    \psarc(0,0){4}{0}{#1}
    \rput{#1}(4;#1){\psline(!0 1 #1 sub 4 mul)}
\end{pspicture}}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \i in {0,0.1,...,1.0}{\obj{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @FelipeFonseca: I read your mind. :-)

Comment: I need to transform this gif in latex :D https://www.google.com/search?q=gif+radians&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Nk2pHJDqqQWnvM%253A%252CcSgQbsWU9OZRNM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRpSoWgZUAe7rhSx5xLvzQ969vx2A&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPie7qo-DhAhVuGLkGHUtjDlkQ9QEwAHoECAgQBA#imgrc=Nk2pHJDqqQWnvM:

Comment: Interesting. PSTricks loads `pgffor`.

Comment: Why i receive this erro?

Comment: @FelipeFonseca: Erro or Euro?

Answer (score 12):

If you wish to produce such animated gifs, you may want to compile

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {180,175,...,90}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) circle (10cm);
\draw[line width=0.15cm, blue] (10,0) arc (0:360:10) ;
\draw[-] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[line width=0.15cm,red,{Circle}-{Circle},shorten >=-2*\pgflinewidth,shorten
<=-2*\pgflinewidth] (10,0) -- ++(\X:10);
\node[scale=15.5, red, right, opacity=0.5] at (2,2) {r};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` and then [convert the resulting pdf with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799)

```
convert -density 300 -delay 34 -loop 0 -alpha remove outfile.pdf ani.gif
```

to get

[image]

When you attempt to patch several of those together, you want to define some command which behaves similarly as the beamer command `\only`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\def\Only<#1-#2>#3{\ifnum\numexpr\X+1>#1
\ifnum\numexpr\X-1<#2
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\DeltaX}{\X+1-#1}
\xdef\DeltaX{\DeltaX}
#3
\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Xmax}{50}
\foreach \X in {0,1,...,\Xmax}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[fat line/.style={line width=0.15cm,red,{Circle}-{Circle},shorten >=-2*\pgflinewidth,shorten
<=-2*\pgflinewidth},cc/.style={line width=0.15cm,
blue},annot/.style={scale=15.5}]
\draw[-] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$y$};
%
\Only<2-5>{
\draw[fat line] (0,0) -- (2*\X,0);
}
\Only<6-10>{
\draw[fat line] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[midway,above,annot,red]{$r$};
}
\Only<11-25>{
\typeout{Delta=\DeltaX}
\draw[cc] (10,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle={\DeltaX*24},radius=10];
\draw[fat line] (0,0) -- ({\DeltaX*24}:10);
}
\Only<26-\Xmax>{
\draw[cc] circle[radius=10cm];
}
\Only<26-35>{\draw[fat line] (10,0)  -- ++ ({180-\DeltaX*9}:10);}
\Only<36-45>{\draw[fat line] (10,0) arc(0:{18*\DeltaX/pi}:10) -- ++
({18*\DeltaX/pi+90}:{10-\DeltaX});}
\Only<46-50>{
\draw [fill=green!70!black,fill opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (3,0) 
node[green!70!black,below,annot,opacity=1]{rad} arc[start angle=0,
end angle={180/pi},radius=3] -- cycle;
\draw[cc,green!70!black] (10,0) -- (0,0) 
-- ({180/pi}:10);
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I clicked ! Ty so much! But just one more question :D There is a way to put marmot's animation frame by frama separed in diferents pdfs? Or it needs to be one?

Comment: Like ive done here: http://prntscr.com/nerl0s and http://prntscr.com/nerl3o

Comment: @FelipeFonseca I added something that might be useful for that task.

Comment: Marmot there is a way to talk with you private?? I really need your help with some questions! If you cant there is no problems

Comment: @FelipeFonseca Sorry, this is not how this site works. Everything here is non-private. You can reach out to users on the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) but the chat is for chat, i.e. not for questions of this type. But you can ask as many questions as you want here, as long as you attach some code that shows what you have tried they will, according to my experience, be well-received and likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Alright, so iam making my university project using LaTeX and my teacher want us to make a animated PDF for the text. The pdf must be photo by photo for example: photo1, photo2, photo3 and etc. I started really well my pdf that it is in this link        [link](https://pt.overleaf.com/5832377531pnrpkvsctgyh)
And I really liked the way that you did the .gif of the line and one of my questions is, how to transform what you have already made to be separed .tex by .tex (photo by photo)... Can you help me ? If it is too complicated i undestand :/ Iam really lost in Latex ;-

Comment: @FelipeFonseca [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472050/121799) you can find an incomplete list of possibilities to create animations with LaTeX. I feel it would be best if you could go through this list with your advisor and then decide what you want. Apart from animated gifs you can create animated pdf, svg (which can be embedded in web sites) and mp4. You can also [employ the full beamer machinery](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475856/121799) for that. I really think you guys should first have a look at the options before making a quick decision how to proceed.

Comment: Alright marmot! I got it the part of the line (http://prntscr.com/nh0owz) changing the number of the \foreach! Ty so much! but how can I do it in this part without using \only???? Help me please man! (http://prntscr.com/nh0p7r) how can i make the curved line changing in each .tex? without making lots of them?

Comment: @FelipeFonseca Please ask a new question. Please note that some users do not like if a user unaccepts an answer just to add an additional request. If you feel you want to unaccept my answer this is up to you but please do not expect me to address additional requests.