# standalone & beamer, preview and crop

Tags: beamer, standalone, preview

Following up on [Using beamer tools in tikz, without creating slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475822/using-beamer-tools-in-tikz-without-creating-slides/707286?noredirect=1#comment1758488_707286):

The combination of `standalone` and `beamer` via `preview` option would be great if it did work, but even this simple example (from standalone manual) does produce just a one-page PDF, instead of the two pages I'd expect.

```
\documentclass[beamer,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{standaloneframe}[] 
\only<1>{ One }
\only<2>{ Two }
\end{standaloneframe}

\end{document}
```

Without preview, it delivers the expected two pages, but non-cropped, of course.

And `crop` instead of `preview` results in `! Improper \prevdepth. \newpage ...everypar {}\fi \par \ifdim \prevdepth` as reported in other questions.

This would be really nice to get working reliably.

Comment: the standalone class explicitly disables the options `preview=false,crop=false,varwidth=false` if you use the beamer option. They simply do not work with the complicated beamer frames.

Comment: A pity... but understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pdfcrop` to crop the pages. Either manually run

```
pdfcrop filename.pdf
```

after the compilation or trick standalone into running it for you (needs shell-escape enabled):

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass[beamer,convert={command=\unexpanded{{/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/pdfcrop\space \infile}}}]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{standaloneframe}[] 
\only<1>{ One one }
\only<2>{ Two }
\end{standaloneframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure. But then, it would crop differently, depending on what is on the slides. The beauty of using animations in beamer would be that the size of the pdf-pages-to-be-included could all stay the same. But probably just not feasible. Thanks!

Comment: If you want all pages to be the same size, just use something like `\geometry{papersize={3cm,3cm}}` to make them smaller.