# PSTricks: Drawing a Horseshoe Magnet with pst-3dplot

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I am attempting to recreate images with horseshoe magnets with PSTricks. I realise there is a [question about this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459590/how-to-draw-a-3d-horseshoe-in-tikz) with TikZ, but I prefer PSTricks.
I would like to draw something like the following with PSTricks (pst-3dplot):
[image: small horseshoe magnet in front of a screen]
[image: cable swing in a horseshoe magnet]

---

I have looked at the `pst-3dplot` package for guidance. They have a definition of `\pstThreeDBox` for drawing a simple rectangular cuboid (dt. Quader). Inspired by that and omitting much of the clever definition by cases of different coordinate perspectives (just go with `coorType=0` for now) I ended up with this code:

```
% Supposed to draw a threeD Horseshoe
\def\pstThreeDHorseshoe{\pst@object{pstThreeDHorseshoe}}
\def\pstThreeDHorseshoe@i(#1,#2,#3){%
  \pst@killglue
  \begingroup
  \addbefore@par{alternative=false,linestyle=\psk@ThreeDplot@visibleLineStyle}%
  \use@keep@par
  \gdef\pst@tempX{#1 }%
  \gdef\pst@tempY{#2 }%
  \gdef\pst@tempZ{#3 }%
  \pstThreeDHorseshoe@ii
}% end pstThreeDHorseshoe@i.
\def\pstThreeDHorseshoe@ii(#1,#2,#3)(#4,#5,#6)(#7,#8,#9){%
  % Top square :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #1 add,\pst@tempY #2 add,\pst@tempZ #3 add)(#4,#5,#6)(#7,#8,#9)%
  % First left square :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #4 add,\pst@tempY #5 add,\pst@tempZ #6 add)(#1 .15 mul,#2 .15 mul,#3 .15 mul)(#7,#8,#9)
  % Second left square :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #4 add #1 .85 mul add,\pst@tempY #5 add #2 .85 mul add,\pst@tempZ #6 add #3 .85 mul add)(#1 .15 mul,#2 .15 mul,#3 .15 mul)(#7,#8,#9)
  % first front bit :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #7 add,\pst@tempY #8 add,\pst@tempZ #9 add)(#1 .15 mul,#2 .15 mul,#3 .15 mul)(#4,#5,#6)
  % second front bit :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #7 add #1 .85 mul add,\pst@tempY #8 add #2 .85 mul add,\pst@tempZ #9 add #3 .85 mul add)(#1 .15 mul,#2 .15 mul,#3 .15 mul)(#4,#5,#6)%
  % Inside square one :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #7 .2 mul add #1 .15 mul add,\pst@tempY #8 .2 mul add #2 .15 mul add,\pst@tempZ #9 .2 mul add #3 .15 mul add)(#4,#5,#6)(#7 .8 mul,#8 .8 mul, #9 .8 mul)%
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #7 .2 mul add #1 .85 mul add,\pst@tempY #8 .2 mul add #2 .85 mul add,\pst@tempZ #9 .2 mul add #3 .85 mul add)(#4,#5,#6)(#7 .8 mul,#8 .8 mul, #9 .8 mul)%
  % Inside square three :
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX #7 .2 mul add #1 .15 mul add,\pst@tempY #8 .2 mul add #2 .15 mul add,\pst@tempZ #9 .2 mul add #3 .15 mul add)(#4,#5,#6)(#1 .7 mul,#2 .7 mul,#3 .7 mul)
  % Back square : 
  \pstThreeDSquare(\pst@tempX,\pst@tempY,\pst@tempZ)(#4,#5,#6)(#1,#2,#3)
\endgroup
\ignorespaces
}% end pstThreeDHorseshoe@ii.
```

and run with

```
\pstThreeDHorseshoe(0,0,0)(0,0,2)(1.5,0,0)(0,3,0)
```

[image: incomplete sketch of a horseshoe magnet with pst-3dplot]

---

Lines that are not supposed to be visible are to be removed. To do so there is the parameter `invisibleLineStyle`, but it is not well documented, just half a page [in this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=poq7DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA394&lpg=PA394&dq=invisibleLineStyle%20pstricks&source=bl&ots=zrp7ENzeYg&sig=ACfU3U1bszJre4x_cICBoIXz_hbJUluUew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiukLO82YXkAhUM16QKHfMGBtgQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=invisibleLineStyle%20pstricks&f=false). I have tried overwriting a line with that linestyle, but to no avail.

I will accept an answer that shows how to deal with this parameter `invisibleLineStyle` and helps me put it in use with the inner structure of the horseshoe shape.

For an edit: Please do suggest a clever way to introduce variables for 0.15, 0.2 so that the dimensions may be changed later.

Comment: https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/ts/aimant/

Answer (score 3):

Only the horseshoe magnet:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(7,8)
    \psset{viewpoint=20 28 15 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=20 60 60 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,solidmemory}
    \psSolid[incolor=red,fillcolor=red,object=parallelepiped,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,grid=false,name=H2](0,-0.375,0.75)
    \psSolid[incolor=red,fillcolor=red,object=parallelepiped,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,grid=false,name=H1](0,2,0.25)
    \psSolid[incolor=red,fillcolor=green,object=parallelepiped,a=2,b=0.75,c=1.5,grid=false,name=H3](0,-0.375,2.25)
    \psSolid[incolor=red,fillcolor=green,object=parallelepiped,a=2,b=4,c=0.5,grid=false,name=H4](0,2,2.75)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The image from the complete example (Link in comment)

[image]

Comment: I tried to tweak your solution to suit my needs by removing the colors and adding the edges with `action=draw`. Lots of lines are drawn, but also the lines that should be invisible:(

Comment: `action=draw` draws everything!