# Are there simple ways to draw parallelepipeds in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw some parallelepipeds in tikz and find the task surprisingly frustrating. For example, I'd like to recreate this figure from wikipedia:

[image]

I've found lots of tikz examples of cubes but none of parallelepipeds. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this goes in the right direction.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[x={(4cm,0cm)},y={({cos(30)*1.5cm},{sin(30)*1.5cm})},
    z={({cos(70)*2cm},{sin(70)*2cm})},line join=round,fill opacity=0.5,thick]
  \draw[fill=cyan] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (0,1,1) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=orange] (0,1,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (1,1,1) -- (0,1,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=cyan] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0,1) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (0,1,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=orange] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a more easy to customize solution (with a less "simple" code) consider:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/parallelepiped/.style={code={
 \tikzset{parallelepiped/.cd,#1}
 \begin{scope}[x={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/a}*1cm,0cm)},
  y={({cos(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/theta})*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/b}*1cm},
    {sin(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/theta})*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/b}*1cm})},
    z={({cos(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/phi})*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/c}*1cm},
    {sin(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/phi})*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/c}*1cm})}
    ,/tikz/parallelepiped/pstyle,pic actions,
    declare function={mysign(\x)=ifthenelse(\x<0,-1,1);}]
  \path[parallelepiped/fall,parallelepiped/fxz] (0,1,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (1,1,1) -- (0,1,1) -- cycle;
  \path[parallelepiped/fall,parallelepiped/fyz,shift={({0.5-0.5*mysign(cos(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/phi}))},0,0)}] 
    (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (0,1,1) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \path[parallelepiped/fall,parallelepiped/fxy,shift={(0,0,{0.5-0.5*mysign(sin(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/theta}))},0,0)}] 
  (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \path[parallelepiped/fall,parallelepiped/fyz,shift={({0.5+0.5*mysign(cos(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/phi}))},0,0)}] 
    (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (0,1,1) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \path[parallelepiped/fall,parallelepiped/fxy,shift={(0,0,{0.5+0.5*mysign(sin(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelepiped/theta}))},0,0)}] 
  (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \path[parallelepiped/fall,parallelepiped/fxz] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}}},parallelepiped/.cd,a/.initial=4,b/.initial=1.5,c/.initial=2,
 theta/.initial=30,phi/.initial=70,pstyle/.style={draw,thick,fill opacity=0.6,
 line join=round},fall/.style={draw},all
 faces/.code={\tikzset{parallelepiped/fall/.style={#1}}},
 fxy/.style={fill=red},xy face/.code={\tikzset{parallelepiped/fxy/.style={#1}}},
 fxz/.style={fill=orange},xz face/.code={\tikzset{parallelepiped/fxz/.style={#1}}},
 fyz/.style={fill=cyan},yz face/.code={\tikzset{parallelepiped/fyz/.style={#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,0) pic{parallelepiped}
   (0,-4) pic{parallelepiped={a=3,phi=110,xz face={fill=yellow}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\path (0,-4) pic{parallelepiped={a=4,phi=90,xz face={fill=yellow}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

To the best of my knowledge, as long as there is no `3dshapes.meta` library, having a highly customizable 3d-like shape always will require some not-so-simple code. (I am considering making the automatic 3d ordering of planes of the `3dtools` library at a given point.)

**EDIT**: Fixed issue with 90 degree angle, big thanks to @ minhthien_2016!

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Out of curiosity, what does `y={({cos(30)*1.5cm},{sin(30)*1.5cm})}` do?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick It sets the y vector. It is an attempt to make things easier for you to customize. If you want a different parallelepiped, you only need to change the angle and the radius of this polar coordinate rather than having to make tons of changes. (I will add an attempt to make it more convenient using a `pic`.)

Comment: This is really cool. Didn't know this was a feature!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I tried `\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path 
 (0,-4) pic{parallelepiped={a=4,phi=90,xz face={fill=yellow}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}` and get two parallelepipeds.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Thanks! Fixed, I think. I did not test it thoroughly yet...

Answer (score 7):

You can try this code. By changing the values `a, b, h, k`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{60}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a=3;b=4;h=3;k=2;
   }] 
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (A) 
     (a,0) coordinate (B)
      (a,b) coordinate (C)
      (0,b) coordinate (D);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=h]
 \path
 (0,k) coordinate (A') 
 (a,k) coordinate (B')
 (a,b+k) coordinate (C')
 (0,b+k) coordinate (D');
 \end{scope}  
 \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5,thick]
\draw[fill=orange] (A) --(B)  -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=cyan] (A) --(B)  -- (B') -- (A') -- cycle;
\draw[fill=red] (B) --(C)  -- (C') -- (B') -- cycle;
\draw[fill=cyan] (C) --(D)  -- (D') -- (C') -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (A) --(D)  -- (D') -- (A') --cycle;
\draw[fill=pink] (A') --(B')  -- (C') -- (D') --cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much to @Schrödinger's cat about your Comment. I see at [Drawing Axis Grid in 3D with Custom Unit Vectors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48774/drawing-axis-grid-in-3d-with-custom-unit-vectors/48776#48776) to repair `canvas is xy plane at z=0` to `canvas is yx plane at z=0` and `canvas is xy plane at z=h` to `canvas is yx plane at z=h`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{60}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a=3;b=4;h=3;k=-2;
   }] 
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (A) 
     (a,0) coordinate (B)
      (a,b) coordinate (C)
      (0,b) coordinate (D);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=h]
 \path
 (0,k) coordinate (A') 
 (a,k) coordinate (B')
 (a,b+k) coordinate (C')
 (0,b+k) coordinate (D');
 \end{scope}  
 \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5,thick]
\draw[fill=orange] (A) --(B)  -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=cyan] (A) --(B)  -- (B') -- (A') -- cycle;
\draw[fill=red] (B) --(C)  -- (C') -- (B') -- cycle;
\draw[fill=cyan] (C) --(D)  -- (D') -- (C') -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (A) --(D)  -- (D') -- (A') --cycle;
\draw[fill=pink] (A') --(B')  -- (C') -- (D') --cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You do not need the [fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48774/drawing-axis-grid-in-3d-with-custom-unit-vectors/48776#48776) if you have a reasonably new TeX installation, i.e. the bug has been fixed some time ago (see the comment below that post).