# Drawing a motor shaft in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'd like to create a picture like the one with TikZ:

[image]

I've already created the electrical part using `circuitikz`. I'd like to add the part on the right (the motor's shaft with arrows), but don't know how to start, actually. Is there a way to draw 3D shapes, maybe? Or should I draw circles and rotate them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) to [V, v=$v(t)$, *-*] (0,2) 
    to [R, l=$R_d$] (2,2)
    to [L, l=$L_d$] (4,2)
    to [V, v<=$e(t)$] (4,0) to [generic] (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I have now: [image: What it looks like now]

What I'm still missing: [image: What I'm still missing]

Comment: Take a look at [Drawing simple 3D cylinders in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be best done with cylinders but for the shading effects one can do some manual construction too.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue!50](0,0) circle (1 and 2);
\draw[top color=blue!25,bottom color=black,middle color=blue!50] (-0.5,2) arc (90:270:1 and 2) -- ++(0.5,0) arc (-90:-270:1 and 2) -- cycle;
\draw[top color=white,bottom color=black!70] (0,3mm) arc (90:270:1.5mm and 3mm)--++(3cm,0) arc (-90:-270:1.5mm and 3mm)-- cycle;
\draw (3cm,3mm) arc (90:-90:1.5mm and 3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @percusse. Is there a chance adding those arrows is just as easy... ?

Comment: @mmm It is. Add `\draw[-latex,thick] (-1,2) arc (90:170:1 and 2);` to the picture to see for an example.