# How to draw the dc motor diagram in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: That's a beautiful diagram. Good luck.

Comment: Have a look at the `circuitikz` package. This will help you start.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can see anything a the link. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60822/drawing-a-motor-shaft-in-tikz. There is, also, the work of the excellent user @percusse.