# tikz-3d shifting rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ptsize}{1.5pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyColor1}{rgb}{0.24, 0.59, 0.32}
\definecolor{MyColor2}{rgb}{0.85, 0.49, 0.19}
\definecolor{MyColor3}{rgb}{0.22, 0.42, 0.69}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

% Define all the nodes necessary for the drawing
\coordinate (alpha1) at (1,-1,0);
\coordinate (alpha2) at (0,1,-1);
\coordinate (alpha3) at (0,0,2);

\coordinate (12) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha2) $);
\coordinate (23) at ($ (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (123) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (223) at ($ (alpha2) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (1223) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha2) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (11223) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha1) + (alpha2) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);

\coordinate (-alpha1) at (-1,1,0);
\coordinate (-alpha2) at (0,-1,1);
\coordinate (-alpha3) at (0,0,-2);

\coordinate (-12) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) $);
\coordinate (-23) at ($ (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-123) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-223) at ($ (-alpha2) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-1223) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-11223) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);

% Draw the black polygon
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.5]
    \draw (alpha3) -- (11223) -- (-alpha3) -- (-11223) -- (alpha3);
    \draw (alpha3) -- (223) -- (-alpha3) -- (-223) -- (alpha3);
\end{scope}

% Draw the nodes for the roots in appropriate colors
\begin{scope}[MyColor3]
    \draw[fill] (alpha3)  circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-alpha3) circle (\ptsize);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[MyColor2]
    \draw[fill] (alpha1)  circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (223)     circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (1223)    circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (11223)   circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-alpha1) circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-223)    circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-1223)   circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-11223)  circle (\ptsize);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[MyColor1]
    \draw[fill] (alpha2) circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (12)      circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (23)      circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (123)     circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-alpha2) circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-12)     circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-23)     circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-123)    circle (\ptsize);
\end{scope}

% Draw the orange rectangle
\draw[MyColor2] (11223) -- (223) -- (-11223) -- (-223) -- (11223);

% Draw the upper green rectangle
\draw[MyColor1] (-alpha2) -- (123) -- (23) -- (-12) -- (-alpha2);

% Draw the upper green rectangle
\draw[MyColor1] (12) -- (-23) -- (-123) -- (alpha2) -- (12);

% Nodes for the names
\node (alpha1-name) at (1.4,-1,0) {$\alpha_1$};
\node (alpha2-name) at (0,1.4,-1) {$\alpha_2$};
\node (alpha3-name) at (0,0,2.3) {$\alpha_3$};

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,15)}]
    \draw[dashed] (alpha1) -- (1223) -- (-alpha1) -- (-1223) -- (alpha1);    
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the picture

[image]

I'm currently trying to shift the dashed rectangle by a certain amount in the `z`-direction of the graph. Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67573/tikz-shift-and-rotate-in-3d) my attempt can be found in the above code

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,15)}]
    \draw[dashed] (alpha1) -- (1223) -- (-alpha1) -- (-1223) -- (alpha1);    
\end{scope}
```

but this doesn't produce any changes. So presumably I'm misunderstanding how this `shift` command is supposed to work... Ideally I'd like to define new coordinates at the edges of the shifted rectangle, but I'm not really sure if this can be done..

Comment: Symbolic coordinates cannot get shifted like this. You *could* do `\begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(0,0,2)}}]
    \draw[dashed] (alpha1) -- (1223) -- (-alpha1) -- (-1223) -- (alpha1);    
\end{scope}` but one has to be careful with `transform canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic coordinates do not get transformed that way. You can transform them with `transform canvas`, e.g.

```
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(0,0,2)}}]
    \draw[dashed] (alpha1) -- (1223) -- (-alpha1) -- (-1223) -- (alpha1);    
\end{scope}
```

However, this is a bit dangerous, for instance the bounding box does not get computed correctly. On the other hand, `tikz-3dplot` loads the `calc` library, so you might do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ptsize}{1.5pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyColor1}{rgb}{0.24, 0.59, 0.32}
\definecolor{MyColor2}{rgb}{0.85, 0.49, 0.19}
\definecolor{MyColor3}{rgb}{0.22, 0.42, 0.69}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

% Define all the nodes necessary for the drawing
\coordinate (alpha1) at (1,-1,0);
\coordinate (alpha2) at (0,1,-1);
\coordinate (alpha3) at (0,0,2);

\coordinate (12) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha2) $);
\coordinate (23) at ($ (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (123) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (223) at ($ (alpha2) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (1223) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha2) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);
\coordinate (11223) at ($ (alpha1) + (alpha1) + (alpha2) + (alpha2) + (alpha3) $);

\coordinate (-alpha1) at (-1,1,0);
\coordinate (-alpha2) at (0,-1,1);
\coordinate (-alpha3) at (0,0,-2);

\coordinate (-12) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) $);
\coordinate (-23) at ($ (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-123) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-223) at ($ (-alpha2) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-1223) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);
\coordinate (-11223) at ($ (-alpha1) + (-alpha1) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha2) + (-alpha3) $);

% Draw the black polygon
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.5]
    \draw (alpha3) -- (11223) -- (-alpha3) -- (-11223) -- (alpha3);
    \draw (alpha3) -- (223) -- (-alpha3) -- (-223) -- (alpha3);
\end{scope}

% Draw the nodes for the roots in appropriate colors
\begin{scope}[MyColor3]
    \draw[fill] (alpha3)  circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-alpha3) circle (\ptsize);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[MyColor2]
    \draw[fill] (alpha1)  circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (223)     circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (1223)    circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (11223)   circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-alpha1) circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-223)    circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-1223)   circle (\ptsize);
    \draw[fill] (-11223)  circle (\ptsize);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[MyColor1]
    \draw[fill] (alpha2) circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (12)      circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (23)      circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (123)     circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (-alpha2) circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (-12)     circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (-23)     circle[radius=\ptsize];
    \draw[fill] (-123)    circle[radius=\ptsize];
\end{scope}

% Draw the orange rectangle
\draw[MyColor2] (11223) -- (223) -- (-11223) -- (-223) -- (11223);

% Draw the upper green rectangle
\draw[MyColor1] (-alpha2) -- (123) -- (23) -- (-12) -- (-alpha2);

% Draw the upper green rectangle
\draw[MyColor1] (12) -- (-23) -- (-123) -- (alpha2) -- (12);

% Nodes for the names
\node (alpha1-name) at (1.4,-1,0) {$\alpha_1$};
\node (alpha2-name) at (0,1.4,-1) {$\alpha_2$};
\node (alpha3-name) at (0,0,2.3) {$\alpha_3$};

%\begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(0,0,2)}}]
\draw[dashed] ($(alpha1)+(0,0,2)$) -- ($(1223)+(0,0,2)$) 
    -- ($(-alpha1)+(0,0,2)$) --($(-1223)+(0,0,2)$) -- cycle;    
%\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I shifted by 2 instead of 15 because 15 is really far away, but you can do that, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.