# Tikz rotation sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, rotating

I am quite new to Latex. I want to create a figure representing the slip systems of unit cells in different crystal orientations. I am using TikZ and was able able to create the figures for the 100 and 110 orientations. However, I am struggling to create the figure for the 111 crystal orientation, since a rotation around two axes is necessary, namely 45 degrees around z and 54.74 degrees around the x axis. The first rotation works fine, but the second rotation is using the already rotated x axis instead of the original x axis. Is there any trick on how to achieve this?

This is my code as an example of one of the four slip systems with a 100 crystal orientation that is to be rotated (no rotation applied here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\def\size{2}
\begin{scope}     
        \coordinate (A0) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (A1) at (0,0,\size);
        \coordinate (A2) at (0,\size,0);
        \coordinate (A3) at (0,\size,\size);
        \coordinate (A4) at (\size,0,0);
        \coordinate (A5) at (\size,0,\size);
        \coordinate (A6) at (\size,\size,0);
        \coordinate (A7) at (\size,\size,\size);
        \draw[black,dashed] (A0) -- (A1);
        \draw[black,dashed] (A0) -- (A2);
        \draw[black,dashed] (A0) -- (A4);
        \fill[red, opacity=0.3] (A0) -- (A3) -- (A6) -- cycle;
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, thick, red] (A0) -- (A3);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, thick, red] (A0) -- (A6);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, thick, red] (A6) -- (A3);
        
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A5);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A6) -- (A7);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Slip systems for a $\langle 100\rangle$ orientation.}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Producing this figure:

[image]

And here is my attempt to represent the 111 crystal orientation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\def\size{2}
\begin{scope}[rotate around z = 45, rotate around y = 54.74]     
        \coordinate (A0) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (A1) at (0,0,\size);
        \coordinate (A2) at (0,\size,0);
        \coordinate (A3) at (0,\size,\size);
        \coordinate (A4) at (\size,0,0);
        \coordinate (A5) at (\size,0,\size);
        \coordinate (A6) at (\size,\size,0);
        \coordinate (A7) at (\size,\size,\size);
        \draw[black,dashed] (A0) -- (A1);
        \draw[black,dashed] (A0) -- (A2);
        \draw[black,dashed] (A0) -- (A4);
        \fill[red, opacity=0.3] (A0) -- (A3) -- (A6) -- cycle;
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, thick, red] (A0) -- (A3);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, thick, red] (A0) -- (A6);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, thick, red] (A6) -- (A3);
        
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A5);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A6) -- (A7);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Slip systems for a $\langle 100\rangle$ orientation.}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Producing this figure:

[image]

Is there any way to make this work in TikZ? Also I am using Overleaf for writing, if this is of any interest.

I appreciate any help on making this work since I have spent quite some time on this and am not able to make it work...

Edit: This image is similar to what I am trying to achieve, but with the reference sample surface being at the left (or right), so the z-axis of my images would be horizontally here. So for the <111> Orientation the {111} plane (red triangle in my images) is parallel to the sample surface (or parallel to the x-y-plane in regards of a x-y-z-system)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you:) Any ideas on how I can achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Can you please show us what you are trying to draw? I have no idea what a 111 crystal orientation should look like:) The web page https://www.universitywafer.com/silicon-wafer-orientation.html has similar pictures, all of which are easy to draw in TikZ.  If the pictures on this web page suffice, then I can show you how to draw them.

Comment: Tank you @314159265358979323!:) The pictures on the pages you linked is showing the crystallographic planes {100}, {110} and {111}. In my pictures the red triangular plane is one of four possible 111 planes. To achieve a crystal orientation of <111> I want to rotate the cube in a way so that the {111} plane is on the x-y-plane (plane normal parallel to z). I have edited my post and added an image which is similar to what I am trying to achieve. Note the rotated representation (their z-axis is horizontal, from left to right)

Comment: Perhaps this post helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67573/tikz-shift-and-rotate-in-3d ?

Comment: @314159265358979323 There's a deleted 'answer' there which is really a question and I think the same as the OP's here: how to do two rotations. And the problem mentioned is the same.

Comment: @314159265358979323 Thank you for the hint, I will try it later today. I will post it here, if I find a solution based on this!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

My first impression, if I understand correctly what you would like to obtain, is that there is a problem of order in the rotations.  The way you wrote your code, you do a rotation around x and then around z.  (By the way, there is a mistake any you wrote y instead of x.)  In the question (your text), you are talking about z first and x after.

You can see both results in the figure.

**Some remarks**

- The dashed edges are misleading since the cube is changing with respect to the point of view.
- I use a different point of view to better grasp the outcome of the composed rotations.
- The way you named the vertices is strange!
- My code below is long since there are three drawings.  But it is almost your code for the cube set into a `pic` element.

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=100pt, bottom=75pt, left=75pt, right=75pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{15pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,3d}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  vertex/.style={scale=.6, fill=orange, fill opacity=.2,
    text=blue, text opacity=1},
  pics/crystal x and z/.style 2 args={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[rotate around z=#2, rotate around x=#1]     
        \path (0,0,0) coordinate (A0) node[vertex] {$0$};
        \path (0,0,\size) coordinate (A1) node[vertex] {$1$};
        \path (0,\size,0) coordinate (A2) node[vertex] {$2$};
        \path (0,\size,\size) coordinate (A3) node[vertex] {$3$};
        \path (\size,0,0) coordinate (A4) node[vertex] {$4$};
        \path (\size,0,\size) coordinate (A5) node[vertex] {$5$};
        \path (\size,\size,0) coordinate (A6) node[vertex] {$6$};
        \path (\size,\size,\size) coordinate (A7) node[vertex] {$7$};
        \fill[red, opacity=0.3] (A0) -- (A3) -- (A6) -- cycle;
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=1ex]}, red] (A0) -- (A3);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=1ex]}, red] (A0) -- (A6);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=1ex]}, thick, green!50!black] (A6) -- (A3);
        
        \draw[black] (A0) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A0) -- (A2);
        \draw[black] (A0) -- (A4);
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A5);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A6) -- (A7);
      \end{scope}
    }
  },
  pics/crystal z and x/.style 2 args={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[rotate around x=#2, rotate around z=#1]     
        \path (0,0,0) coordinate (A0) node[vertex] {$0$};
        \path (0,0,\size) coordinate (A1) node[vertex] {$1$};
        \path (0,\size,0) coordinate (A2) node[vertex] {$2$};
        \path (0,\size,\size) coordinate (A3) node[vertex] {$3$};
        \path (\size,0,0) coordinate (A4) node[vertex] {$4$};
        \path (\size,0,\size) coordinate (A5) node[vertex] {$5$};
        \path (\size,\size,0) coordinate (A6) node[vertex] {$6$};
        \path (\size,\size,\size) coordinate (A7) node[vertex] {$7$};
        \fill[red, opacity=0.3] (A0) -- (A3) -- (A6) -- cycle;
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=1ex]}, red] (A0) -- (A3);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=1ex]}, red] (A0) -- (A6);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=1ex]}, thick, green!50!black] (A6) -- (A3);
        
        \draw[black] (A0) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A0) -- (A2);
        \draw[black] (A0) -- (A4);
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw[black] (A2) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A3) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A6);
        \draw[black] (A4) -- (A5);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A1);
        \draw[black] (A5) -- (A7);
        \draw[black] (A6) -- (A7);
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{165} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, tdplot_main_coords,
    evaluate={\size = 2; \a = 3.5;}]
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (\a,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,\a,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\a) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path (0, 0) pic {crystal x and z={0}{0}};    
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, tdplot_main_coords,
    evaluate={\size = 2; \a = 3.5;}]
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (\a,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,\a,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\a) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path (0, 0) pic {crystal x and z={54.74}{0}};    
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, tdplot_main_coords,
    evaluate={\size = 2; \a = 3.5;}]
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (\a,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,\a,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\a) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path (0, 0) pic {crystal x and z={54.74}{45}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Rotations around $Ox$ first and $Oz$ second}
  \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{165} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, tdplot_main_coords,
    evaluate={\size = 2; \a = 3.5;}]
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (\a,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,\a,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\a) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path (0, 0) pic {crystal z and x={0}{0}};    
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, tdplot_main_coords,
    evaluate={\size = 2; \a = 3.5;}]
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (\a,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,\a,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\a) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path (0, 0) pic {crystal z and x={45}{0}};    
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, tdplot_main_coords,
    evaluate={\size = 2; \a = 3.5;}]
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (\a,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,\a,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[-latex, blue] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\a) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path (0, 0) pic {crystal z and x={45}{54.74}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Rotations around $Oz$ first and $Ox$ second}
  \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```