# Making geometry worksheets in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

I work as a math tutor and I'd like to make geometry worksheets for 7th grade students: These worksheets would include finding the area of various polygons, and finding the volume of various shapes. I would just need some package that can draw the shape for me and allow me to insert various lengths/widths/heights. Is there such a package?

Edit:

Thank you for the warm welcomes. Just to give more details I would be looking to make something like this

[image: worksheet]

Is this possible in the TikZ package?

Comment: “draw the shape for me and allow me to insert various lengths…” Depending on how much automation you look for, that's probably available in TikZ. Look at the `shapes.greometric` library; the measuring is a little more manual. In any case, I think you should rephrase your question and give more exact details. Welcome to the site, anyways!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.  There are plenty of packages for drawing stuff, see [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597) TikZ is perhaps the most popular (at least on this site).

Comment: BTW, I'm sort of in that business myself (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/geometry/index.htm).  You night also look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254039/the-belt-for-chain-of-gears/254055#254055 , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253027/find-cylinder-tangent-in-3d/253078#253078 , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144193/how-do-i-put-a-die-roll-at-the-top-of-each-page/144474#144474 etc.

Comment: Yes, it's possible :) look at enumerate, multicols, adjustbox and then tikz for the shapes

Comment: For that simple diagrams, I wouldn't use anything more than basic TikZ to be honest. May be create a key for the 90º angles mark, but everything else is straight with TikZ (or any other drawing package).

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far in terms of code? Then we can focus on whatever you're having trouble with.

Comment: Do your students really have to use both metric and imperial measurements?

Answer (score 10):

Here is something to get you started. The configuration assumes that each row of the worksheet will include 3 questions. However, you can easily adapt it if necessary.

As far as the figures are concerned, the only one which seems worth making a little more automatic is the circle because that always follows the same structure. In other cases, the labels etc. vary and, since the shapes are simple, you might just as soon draw them as you wish.

`tikzqn` is an environment which will automatically number the questions and insert answer spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcounter{tikzqn}
\newcounter{tikzrow}
\newenvironment{tikzqn}%
{%
  \stepcounter{tikzqn}%
  \stepcounter{tikzrow}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \sffamily\thetikzqn)\par\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north), font=\sffamily, thick]
}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \bigskip\vfill\par
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \ifnum\value{tikzrow}=3\setcounter{tikzrow}{0}%
  \bigskip\par
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
  {\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \sffamily Answer:\hrulefill\bigskip\par
  \end{minipage}\hfill}%
\fi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{cabin}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  pics/my circle/.style 2 args={
    code={
      \draw circle (#1);
      \draw [fill] (0,0) circle (1pt) -- (#1,0) node [midway, above] {#2};
    }
  },
}
\noindent
\begin{tikzqn}
   \pic {my circle={20mm}{71cm}};
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(40mm,0) node [midway, below] {37cm} -- ++(0,20mm) node [midway, right, anchor=north, sloped] {21cm} -| cycle;
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (a) -- ++(20mm,0) node [midway, below] {10cm} -- ++(-10mm,25mm) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
  \draw [dashed] (a -| c) -- (c) node [pos=.35, right, anchor=south, sloped] {8cm};
  \draw (a -| c) ++ (0,5pt) -| ++(5pt,-5pt);
\end{tikzqn}

\begin{tikzqn}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,40mm) node [midway, right, anchor=south, sloped] {3m} -| ++(10mm,-40mm) -- cycle node [midway, below, anchor=north] {75cm};
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \pic {my circle={15mm}{4cm}};
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \draw (0,0) -| ++(20mm,25mm) coordinate [midway] (b) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
  \path (0,0) -- (b) node [midway, below, anchor=north] {11cm} -- (c) node [midway, right, anchor=north, sloped] {17cm};
  \draw (b) rectangle ++(-5pt,5pt);
\end{tikzqn}

\begin{tikzqn}
  \node (dia) [draw, shape=diamond, minimum size=30mm] {};
  \node [rotate=45, anchor=north] at (dia.south east)  {6cm};
  \draw (dia.north) ++(-2.5pt,-2.5pt) -- ++(2.5pt,-2.5pt) -- ++(2.5pt,2.5pt);
  \draw (dia.south) ++(-2.5pt,2.5pt) -- ++(2.5pt,2.5pt) -- ++(2.5pt,-2.5pt);
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \node (sc) [draw, shape=semicircle, minimum size=25mm, label=below:46mm] {};
  \draw [dashed] (sc.south) -- (sc.north) node [midway, left, anchor=south, sloped] {23mm};
  \draw (sc.south) ++(5pt,0) |- ++(-5pt,5pt);
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(35mm,0) coordinate (a) node [midway, below, anchor=north] {14cm} arc (-90:90:15mm) coordinate (b) -| cycle;
  \draw [dashed] (a -| b) -- (b) node [midway, right, anchor=south, sloped] {5cm};
  \draw [dashed] ([yshift=15mm]a) coordinate (c) -- ++(15mm,0) node [midway, below, anchor=north] {2.5cm};
  \draw (a) ++(-5pt,0) |- ++(5pt,5pt) (c) ++(5pt,0) |- ++(-5pt,5pt);
\end{tikzqn}

\begin{tikzqn}
  \node (tri) [draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, label=-90:10cm, minimum size=45mm] {};
  \path (tri.corner 2) -- (tri.corner 1) node [midway, left, anchor=south, sloped] {10cm};
  \path (tri.corner 3) -- (tri.corner 1) node [midway, left, anchor=south, sloped] {10cm};
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \node (sq) [draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, label=-90:8cm, minimum size=40mm] {};
  \path (sq.south east) -- (sq.north east) node [midway, right, sloped, anchor=north] {8cm};
\end{tikzqn}
\begin{tikzqn}
  \node [draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, label=-90:7cm, minimum size=35mm] {};
\end{tikzqn}

\end{document}
```

[image: geometry worksheet]

Comment: Thanks for changing the orientation of the vertical lengths' labels.

Comment: @Manuel Why? Or is that an objection?

Comment: I just reread, and it definitely looks like an objection *hehe* It was a real thanks. Why? Because the other way is just antinatural for my body.

Comment: @Manuel Until you said it, I didn't even realise I'd done it. I think I just did it the way which 'made sense' to me. I don't know if that is because this is a more common orientation or because of my eyes or what.

Comment: It's the most common way because it's the standard in acotation (I think some kind of ISO or something like that). In any case it was the natural way to my body quite before I found out about it in school (I don't know why the hell I was thinking about this kind of things when I was soooo young).