# Tikz : How to control the the ellipse at the top of a cylinder node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape, tikz-node

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum
height=3cm,minimum width=2cm] {};

\node (B) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum
height=3cm,minimum width=2cm, below=0.3cm of A]
{Wider?};

\node (C) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,minimum
height=3cm,minimum width=2cm, below=0.3cm of B]
{Why is the Ellipse wider?};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Generates:

[image]

The ellipse at the top of the cylinder node gets less oblate as the text inside the node gets wider. How do you control this?

I would like to keep approximately the same aspect of the ellipse despite stretching to fit text.

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable as that is much more use than a fragment.

Comment: Have you read what the manual says about `aspect`?

Comment: I still have not found a direct reference to how aspect affects the cylinder node. I can use this to get my desired effect, but it requires a slightly different aspect depending on the overall width of the cylinder. I would like to understand how to set a single aspect that provides consistent results for a wide range of cyllinder node sizes, i.e. being able to set the aspect of the ellipse at the top, however as far as I can tell this is not what aspect sets as in certain instances, aspect can be set to a number larger than 1 and still produce an oblate ellipse.

Comment: When you ask `why is the ellipse wider?`, what do you mean? It is wider, clearly, because the text you are putting in it needs more space, so the cylinder has to expand to accommodate it. That is just how nodes work: unless you override it, they are sized to fit their contents. If the cylinder is wider, obviously the ellipse has to be wider, too, else it would no longer be a cylinder but two lines and two detached ellipses.

Comment: And you've still not provided a working example.

Comment: The default aspect ratio depends on other factors.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267266/how-to-draw-multi-position-cylinder-with-tikz/267364?s=1|0.8706#267364 for setting the aspect directly.