# Drawing a cut cylinder with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I'm trying to use tikz to create the attached image, but I'm not sure this is possible. I know I can use the package to draw cylinders, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/drawing-3d-cylinder) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267266/how-to-draw-multi-position-cylinder-with-tikz). But I don't think I can use the `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` to provide the cut shown in the attachment. Is this at all feasible with tikz?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This draws such a cylinder and also uses `patterns.meta` for the ellipses.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta,decorations.pathmorphing} 
\begin{document}
\def\pk#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/#1}}
\tikzdeclarepattern{name=lines,
  parameters={
      \pk{size},
      \pk{angle},
      \pk{line width},
      \pk{gap},
  },
  bounding box={(-.1pt,-.1pt) and
    (\pk{size}+.1pt,
     {\pk{gap}+.1pt})},
  tile size={(\pk{size},
              {\pk{gap}})},
  tile transformation={rotate=\pk{angle}},
  defaults={
    size/.initial=5pt,
    angle/.initial=0,
    line width/.initial=.4pt,
    gap/.initial=3pt
}, code={
\draw[line width=\pk{line width}] 
(0,0) -- ({\pk{size}},0) ;
} }
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/fcylinder/.style={code={
 \tikzset{fcylinder/.cd,#1}
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fcylinder/##1}}
 \draw[fill=gray!30] (0,\pv{r}) 
    arc[start angle=90,end angle=270,x radius=\pv{r}*\pv{aspect},y radius=\pv{r}]
    -- (\pv{h},-\pv{r}) to[out=180,in=-120] 
    (\pv{h},0) to[out=60,in=0] (\pv{h},\pv{r}) -- cycle;
 \draw[fill=gray!60]  (\pv{h},-\pv{r}) to[out=180,in=-120]  (\pv{h},0)
 to[out=-60,in=0] cycle;
 \draw[fcylinder/finish] (0,\pv{r}) 
  arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,x radius=\pv{r}*\pv{aspect},y radius=\pv{r}];
}},fcylinder/.cd,r/.initial=5mm,h/.initial=1cm,aspect/.initial=1/3,
    finish/.style={solid}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=Dirichlet]
  \path[pattern={lines[line width=.8pt,angle=30]}] 
  (0,0) circle[x radius=5mm,y radius=1.5cm]; 
  \path (0,0) pic{fcylinder={finish/.style=dashed}};
 \end{scope} 
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm,local bounding box=Neumann]
  \path (0,0) pic{fcylinder};
  \draw[very thick,-stealth] (0,0) -- node[above] {$\bar N$}++ (-1,0);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,local bounding box=Robin]
  \path[pattern={lines[line width=.8pt,angle=30]}] 
  (0,0) circle[x radius=5mm,y radius=1.5cm]; 
  \path (1,0) pic{fcylinder};
  \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment length=1.5mm,amplitude=2mm,
  pre length=2mm,post length=2mm}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
 \end{scope}
 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, how did you come up with that parametrization for the cylinder?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Just guessing. (Surprisingly the first thing I tried looked reasonable so I took it.)

Comment: How do I turn the cut part to the other side?