# Cylinder with specific orientation

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I realize there are a couple of questions about cylinders in Tikz, but I haven't figured out how to add them to my image.

I have something like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{46+90} % rotate 60 degrees around x axis, then 105 degrees about z
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',           % arrow tip
                    tdplot_main_coords,   % 
                    scale=0.5               % scale
                    ]  
   % XYZ axis
   \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{\textbf{x}};
   \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,6,0) node[anchor=north]{\textbf{y}};
   \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,6) node[anchor=south]{\textbf{z}};
    \draw[dotted] (0,0,0) circle (15);
    \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=3] coordinates{(15,0,0)} node[anchor=south east]{S}; 

% my lousy attempt
 \node [cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.5,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=0.25cm,shape border      
   rotate=0,cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=red!30,cylinder end fill=red!5] at (15,0,0){S};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where there is a 3D coordinate system, and a big circle with an specific coordinate "S" on where I want a cylinder, oriented towards (0,0,0). However I can't seem to achieve this orientation.

If the only way to approach this is to manually draw the cylinder, then I have a problem with joining the "lids". I can draw 2 filled circles in another orientation than XY plane (as @john Kormylo shows in the comments) but I have no idea how to "attach" those circles

Comment: I think you need a `\documentclass...` ;. The best option might be to draw the cylinder rather than using a node. That way, you can use the `tikz-3dplot` stuff for the rotation and calculations?

Comment: @cfr oh yeah, this was supposed to mean just a MVCE (ofc my figure its way more complex), and i forgot it! It could be, but, I have no idea how to approach that case then!

Comment: Sorry, but the acronyms elude me....

Comment: I think you can probably just draw the outline in the normal way but you need to use x-y-z rather than the x-y coordinates which I'm guessing the node is using. (At least, effectively using.)

Comment: @cfr apologies, in the main stackoverflow it is a common one. Minimum Verifiable Complete Example. What do you mean by "draw the outline in the normal way". Apologies, I just started with Tikz, still trying to work my head around it.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I think what the local dialect calls an MWE (Minimum Working Example).

Comment: I just meant that if you draw, say, the sides using `\draw (15,0,0) -- (13,0,0) ...`, say, then they should be orientated in the way you want. Or you could rotate the node. But rotation is complicated because you have to figure out the right angle. I just thought it might be easier to use the coordinating system you've got, even though it means not using the convenience of the node shape.

Comment: @cfr that would mean drawing a pipe and some lids in the coordinate system, right?

Comment: Do you just want a cylinder, or do you want to write curved text on the sides?  BTW, with tikz-3d circles can only be drawn in the x-y plane, so you will probably need a rotated coordinate system.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254820/tikz-pair-of-compasse-rendering-contest/254866?s=2|0.4564#254866

Comment: @JohnKormylo I want just the cylinder, the text can be next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not easily achieved. Because node shapes are always drawn on the canvas, but you need a three-dimensional one, we need to draw the cylinder by hand.
This is easily done in the rotated reference frame `tikz-3dplot` has ready. I set this frame in such a way that the face of the cylinder is in this plane. The circular face is easily drawn then. The only problem is drawing the side lines at the right position. For this we need to find the right angle in this plane, for which I created a macro a while back [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253027/find-cylinder-tangent-in-3d), which I call `\rotatedtangentangle` here.

Putting everything together yields:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{46+90} % rotate 60 degrees around x axis, then 105 degrees about z
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',           % arrow tip
                    tdplot_main_coords,   % 
                    scale=0.5               % scale
                    ]

\newcommand{\rotatedtangentangle}[1]{%
    % find directions of projection
    \path[tdplot_rotated_coords] (1,0,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\axisxx}{\axisxy}
    \path[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,1,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\axisyx}{\axisyy}
    \path[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\axiszx}{\axiszy}
    % angle of tangent
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtang}{atan(-\axiszy/\axiszx)+180}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angkorr}{atan(\axisyy/\axisyx)/2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{\rtang+\angkorr}
}%

   % XYZ axis
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{\textbf{x}};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,6,0) node[anchor=north]{\textbf{y}};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,6) node[anchor=south]{\textbf{z}};
    \draw[dotted] (0,0,0) circle (15);

    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{90} % create rotated frame
    \rotatedtangentangle{\tangent} % compute tanget angle
    % shift rotated frame to center of cylinder
    \coordinate (shift) at (15,0,0);
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(shift)}
    % draw cylinder
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        % draw the side lines and arc of the cylinder (here length 1, radius 0.5)
        \draw[fill=red!30]
            (0,0,-1) ++(\tangent:0.5) -- ++(0,0,1) arc (\tangent:\tangent-180:0.5) -- ++(0,0,-1);
        % draw the circular face (radius 0.5)
        \draw[fill=red!30] (0,0,-1) circle [radius=0.5];
        \node at (0,0,0) {S};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Could you please give a hint on how to change the cylinder diymensions?

Comment: Since the cylinder is drawn in the last scope, you may simply change the appropriate values. The radius of the circle is used as `radius` as well as in the `arc` (its `start angle:end angle:radius`). The length of the cylinder is drawn in absolute coordinates, here 1cm. Just change the value e.g. to `-- ++(0,0,2)` to get twice the length.

Comment: I am sure one could wrap this up in a nice makro though...