# Getting started drawing basic 3D objects with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, metapost, svg, postscript

Is it possible to draw this with Ti*k*Z (or perhaps a similar package related to postscript, metapost, SVG, etc.)?
[image]
Sorry, I don't have much to offer this time. I usually like to provide a bunch of code (or something useful or of some value) with my questions, but I'm not sure where to begin with this one, or if it's even possible or if Ti*k*Z is even designed for this style of illustration.

Here's a few similar/related vector images I've seen online at Wikimedia Commons that I think are great; shown in order of their gradually increasing complexity. I'm not sure what software was used to draw them, but if I can get the hang of this, I'd like to eventually work my way up to producing illustrations of this kind of quality:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have some postscript code to draw cylinders [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274863/how-to-trap-my-surface-patches-to-prevent-the-background-from-bleeding-through)

Comment: Drawing cylinder with the correct prospective in TikZ it's not so easy. Look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/drawing-simple-3d-cylinders-in-tikz/500999#500999).

Answer (score 1):

A first try with [sketch](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sketch4latex/)

[image]

The code is:

```
def I [1,0,0]
def myCab {
special |
\definecolor{fcab}{HTML}{b8c5de}
\definecolor{scab}{HTML}{d8d9eb}
\definecolor{tcab}{HTML}{ffffb7}
\definecolor{focab}{HTML}{ffdbab}
| [lay=under]
sweep [draw=fcab!80!black,fill=fcab!80!black]{ 30<>, rotate(360/30, [I]) }
line[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-1,-0.1)(1,-0.1)

sweep [draw=scab!80!black,fill=scab!80!black]{ 40<>, rotate(360/40, [I]) }
line[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1,-1)(3,-1)

sweep [draw=tcab!80!black,fill=tcab!80!black]{ 50<>, rotate(360/50, [I]) }
line[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3,-2)(5,-2)

sweep [draw=focab!80!black,fill=focab!80!black]{ 60<>, rotate(360/60, [I]) }
line[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5,-3)(7,-3)
}

put {
rotate (35,(0,0,0),[0,1,0])
then
rotate (30,(0,0,0),[1,0,0])
}
{myCab}
global { language tikz }
```

The corresponding TikZ picture is:

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% Sketch output, version 0.3 (build 7, Fri Feb 24 21:22:17 2012)
% Output language: PGF/TikZ,LaTeX
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]

\definecolor{fcab}{HTML}{b8c5de}
\definecolor{scab}{HTML}{d8d9eb}
\definecolor{tcab}{HTML}{ffffb7}
\definecolor{focab}{HTML}{ffdbab}
\filldraw[draw=focab!80!black,fill=focab!80!black](4.096,-1.164)--(4.276,-1.278)--(4.454,-1.363)--(4.627,-1.417)--(4.796,-1.439)--(4.956,-1.43)--(5.107,-1.39)--(5.247,-1.319)--(5.375,-1.218)--(5.488,-1.087)--(5.586,-.929)--(5.668,-.745)--(5.732,-.537)--(5.779,-.308)--(5.807,-.06)--(5.816,.205)--(5.807,.484)--(5.779,.772)--(5.732,1.068)--(5.668,1.368)--(5.586,1.669)--(5.488,1.967)--(5.375,2.259)--(5.247,2.543)--(5.107,2.814)--(4.956,3.07)--(4.796,3.308)--(4.627,3.525)--(4.454,3.72)--(4.276,3.889)--(4.096,4.032)--(3.916,4.146)--(3.738,4.231)--(3.564,4.285)--(3.396,4.307)--(3.235,4.298)--(3.084,4.258)--(2.944,4.187)--(2.817,4.086)--(2.704,3.955)--(2.606,3.797)--(2.524,3.613)--(2.459,3.405)--(2.413,3.176)--(2.384,2.928)--(2.375,2.663)--(2.384,2.384)--(2.413,2.096)--(2.459,1.8)--(2.524,1.5)--(2.606,1.199)--(2.704,.901)--(2.817,.609)--(2.944,.325)--(3.084,.054)--(3.235,-.202)--(3.396,-.44)--(3.564,-.657)--(3.738,-.852)--(3.916,-1.021)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](3.235,4.298)--(4.874,4.872)--(4.723,4.832)--(3.084,4.258)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.107,-1.39)--(6.745,-.817)--(6.885,-.745)--(5.247,-1.319)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](3.396,4.307)--(5.034,4.881)--(4.874,4.872)--(3.235,4.298)--cycle;
\filldraw[draw=tcab!80!black,fill=tcab!80!black](2.457,-.872)--(2.601,-.961)--(2.743,-1.021)--(2.88,-1.052)--(3.01,-1.052)--(3.132,-1.022)--(3.243,-.963)--(3.341,-.875)--(3.426,-.759)--(3.495,-.618)--(3.548,-.454)--(3.584,-.269)--(3.602,-.066)--(3.602,.152)--(3.584,.38)--(3.548,.617)--(3.495,.857)--(3.426,1.097)--(3.341,1.333)--(3.243,1.562)--(3.132,1.78)--(3.01,1.984)--(2.88,2.169)--(2.743,2.334)--(2.601,2.476)--(2.457,2.592)--(2.314,2.681)--(2.172,2.742)--(2.035,2.772)--(1.905,2.773)--(1.783,2.743)--(1.672,2.684)--(1.574,2.596)--(1.489,2.48)--(1.419,2.339)--(1.366,2.175)--(1.331,1.99)--(1.313,1.787)--(1.313,1.569)--(1.331,1.34)--(1.366,1.104)--(1.419,.864)--(1.489,.624)--(1.574,.387)--(1.672,.159)--(1.783,-.059)--(1.905,-.263)--(2.035,-.449)--(2.172,-.614)--(2.314,-.755)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.247,-1.319)--(6.885,-.745)--(7.013,-.644)--(5.375,-1.218)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](3.564,4.285)--(5.202,4.858)--(5.034,4.881)--(3.396,4.307)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.375,-1.218)--(7.013,-.644)--(7.126,-.514)--(5.488,-1.087)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](3.738,4.231)--(5.376,4.804)--(5.202,4.858)--(3.564,4.285)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.488,-1.087)--(7.126,-.514)--(7.224,-.356)--(5.586,-.929)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](1.905,2.773)--(3.543,3.346)--(3.421,3.317)--(1.783,2.743)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.132,-1.022)--(4.77,-.449)--(4.881,-.389)--(3.243,-.963)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](3.916,4.146)--(5.554,4.72)--(5.376,4.804)--(3.738,4.231)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.586,-.929)--(7.224,-.356)--(7.306,-.172)--(5.668,-.745)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.035,2.772)--(3.673,3.346)--(3.543,3.346)--(1.905,2.773)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.243,-.963)--(4.881,-.389)--(4.98,-.301)--(3.341,-.875)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](4.096,4.032)--(5.734,4.606)--(5.554,4.72)--(3.916,4.146)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.668,-.745)--(7.306,-.172)--(7.371,.036)--(5.732,-.537)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.172,2.742)--(3.81,3.315)--(3.673,3.346)--(2.035,2.772)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.341,-.875)--(4.98,-.301)--(5.064,-.186)--(3.426,-.759)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](4.276,3.889)--(5.914,4.463)--(5.734,4.606)--(4.096,4.032)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.732,-.537)--(7.371,.036)--(7.417,.265)--(5.779,-.308)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.314,2.681)--(3.952,3.255)--(3.81,3.315)--(2.172,2.742)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.426,-.759)--(5.064,-.186)--(5.134,-.045)--(3.495,-.618)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](4.454,3.72)--(6.092,4.293)--(5.914,4.463)--(4.276,3.889)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.779,-.308)--(7.417,.265)--(7.445,.514)--(5.807,-.06)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.457,2.592)--(4.096,3.166)--(3.952,3.255)--(2.314,2.681)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.495,-.618)--(5.134,-.045)--(5.187,.12)--(3.548,-.454)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](4.627,3.525)--(6.266,4.099)--(6.092,4.293)--(4.454,3.72)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.807,-.06)--(7.445,.514)--(7.455,.779)--(5.816,.205)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](.559,1.244)--(2.197,1.818)--(2.12,1.802)--(.482,1.228)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.601,2.476)--(4.24,3.05)--(4.096,3.166)--(2.457,2.592)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.156,-.655)--(2.795,-.081)--(2.863,-.042)--(1.225,-.615)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.548,-.454)--(5.187,.12)--(5.223,.305)--(3.584,-.269)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](4.796,3.308)--(6.434,3.881)--(6.266,4.099)--(4.627,3.525)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](.642,1.237)--(2.28,1.811)--(2.197,1.818)--(.559,1.244)--cycle;
\filldraw[draw=scab!80!black,fill=scab!80!black](.819,-.579)--(.909,-.633)--(.996,-.663)--(1.08,-.671)--(1.156,-.655)--(1.225,-.615)--(1.283,-.554)--(1.33,-.471)--(1.365,-.37)--(1.386,-.253)--(1.393,-.123)--(1.386,.018)--(1.365,.165)--(1.33,.315)--(1.283,.464)--(1.225,.61)--(1.156,.747)--(1.08,.872)--(.996,.984)--(.909,1.078)--(.819,1.153)--(.729,1.206)--(.642,1.237)--(.559,1.244)--(.482,1.228)--(.414,1.189)--(.355,1.127)--(.308,1.045)--(.274,.944)--(.253,.827)--(.246,.696)--(.253,.556)--(.274,.409)--(.308,.259)--(.355,.109)--(.414,-.036)--(.482,-.173)--(.559,-.299)--(.642,-.41)--(.729,-.505)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.816,.205)--(7.455,.779)--(7.445,1.057)--(5.807,.484)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.225,-.615)--(2.863,-.042)--(2.921,.02)--(1.283,-.554)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.743,2.334)--(4.381,2.908)--(4.24,3.05)--(2.601,2.476)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.584,-.269)--(5.223,.305)--(5.241,.508)--(3.602,-.066)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](4.956,3.07)--(6.594,3.643)--(6.434,3.881)--(4.796,3.308)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](.729,1.206)--(2.368,1.78)--(2.28,1.811)--(.642,1.237)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.283,-.554)--(2.921,.02)--(2.969,.102)--(1.33,-.471)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.807,.484)--(7.445,1.057)--(7.417,1.346)--(5.779,.772)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](2.88,2.169)--(4.518,2.743)--(4.381,2.908)--(2.743,2.334)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.602,-.066)--(5.241,.508)--(5.241,.725)--(3.602,.152)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.107,2.814)--(6.745,3.387)--(6.594,3.643)--(4.956,3.07)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](.819,1.153)--(2.457,1.726)--(2.368,1.78)--(.729,1.206)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.33,-.471)--(2.969,.102)--(3.003,.203)--(1.365,-.37)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.779,.772)--(7.417,1.346)--(7.371,1.642)--(5.732,1.068)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.01,1.984)--(4.648,2.557)--(4.518,2.743)--(2.88,2.169)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.247,2.543)--(6.885,3.116)--(6.745,3.387)--(5.107,2.814)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.602,.152)--(5.241,.725)--(5.223,.954)--(3.584,.38)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](.909,1.078)--(2.547,1.652)--(2.457,1.726)--(.819,1.153)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.732,1.068)--(7.371,1.642)--(7.306,1.942)--(5.668,1.368)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.365,-.37)--(3.003,.203)--(3.024,.32)--(1.386,-.253)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.375,2.259)--(7.013,2.833)--(6.885,3.116)--(5.247,2.543)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.132,1.78)--(4.77,2.354)--(4.648,2.557)--(3.01,1.984)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.668,1.368)--(7.306,1.942)--(7.224,2.242)--(5.586,1.669)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.584,.38)--(5.223,.954)--(5.187,1.19)--(3.548,.617)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.488,1.967)--(7.126,2.541)--(7.013,2.833)--(5.375,2.259)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](.996,.984)--(2.635,1.557)--(2.547,1.652)--(.909,1.078)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=focab,fill=focab](5.586,1.669)--(7.224,2.242)--(7.126,2.541)--(5.488,1.967)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.386,-.253)--(3.024,.32)--(3.031,.451)--(1.393,-.123)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.243,1.562)--(4.881,2.136)--(4.77,2.354)--(3.132,1.78)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.548,.617)--(5.187,1.19)--(5.134,1.43)--(3.495,.857)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.08,.872)--(2.718,1.446)--(2.635,1.557)--(.996,.984)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.341,1.333)--(4.98,1.907)--(4.881,2.136)--(3.243,1.562)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.393,-.123)--(3.031,.451)--(3.024,.591)--(1.386,.018)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.495,.857)--(5.134,1.43)--(5.064,1.67)--(3.426,1.097)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=tcab,fill=tcab](3.426,1.097)--(5.064,1.67)--(4.98,1.907)--(3.341,1.333)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.156,.747)--(2.795,1.32)--(2.718,1.446)--(1.08,.872)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.386,.018)--(3.024,.591)--(3.003,.738)--(1.365,.165)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.225,.61)--(2.863,1.183)--(2.795,1.32)--(1.156,.747)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.365,.165)--(3.003,.738)--(2.969,.889)--(1.33,.315)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.283,.464)--(2.921,1.038)--(2.863,1.183)--(1.225,.61)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=scab,fill=scab](1.33,.315)--(2.969,.889)--(2.921,1.038)--(1.283,.464)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.842,-.191)--(.796,.383)--(.785,.381)--(-.853,-.193)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.785,-.381)--(.853,.193)--(.862,.198)--(-.777,-.375)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.831,-.194)--(.807,.38)--(.796,.383)--(-.842,-.191)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.777,-.375)--(.862,.198)--(.869,.208)--(-.769,-.366)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.819,-.2)--(.819,.373)--(.807,.38)--(-.831,-.194)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.769,-.366)--(.869,.208)--(.874,.221)--(-.765,-.353)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.807,-.211)--(.831,.363)--(.819,.373)--(-.819,-.2)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.765,-.353)--(.874,.221)--(.876,.237)--(-.762,-.337)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.796,-.224)--(.842,.349)--(.831,.363)--(-.807,-.211)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.762,-.337)--(.876,.237)--(.876,.255)--(-.762,-.318)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.785,-.241)--(.853,.333)--(.842,.349)--(-.796,-.224)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.762,-.318)--(.876,.255)--(.874,.275)--(-.765,-.299)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.777,-.259)--(.862,.314)--(.853,.333)--(-.785,-.241)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.765,-.299)--(.874,.275)--(.869,.295)--(-.769,-.279)--cycle;
\filldraw[line width=0pt,draw=fcab,fill=fcab](-.769,-.279)--(.869,.295)--(.862,.314)--(-.777,-.259)--cycle;
\filldraw[draw=fcab!80!black,fill=fcab!80!black](-.819,-.373)--(-.807,-.38)--(-.796,-.383)--(-.785,-.381)--(-.777,-.375)--(-.769,-.366)--(-.765,-.353)--(-.762,-.337)--(-.762,-.318)--(-.765,-.299)--(-.769,-.279)--(-.777,-.259)--(-.785,-.241)--(-.796,-.224)--(-.807,-.211)--(-.819,-.2)--(-.831,-.194)--(-.842,-.191)--(-.853,-.193)--(-.862,-.198)--(-.869,-.208)--(-.874,-.221)--(-.876,-.237)--(-.876,-.255)--(-.874,-.275)--(-.869,-.295)--(-.862,-.314)--(-.853,-.333)--(-.842,-.349)--(-.831,-.363)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}% End sketch output
\end{document}
```