# How does tikz parse the coordinates surrounded by brackets like (2cm, 1cm)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a question about the coordinates in tikz: when I set the style of a node by `shift={(1, 1)}`, what happens and how are the coordinates parsed into corresponding offset applied to each point of the graph to be drawn?

And if I want to define a pgfkey with a coordinate-like parameter so that when I pass a string like `(2, 3, 4)`, it is parsed and the values are saved to three macros respectively, is it feasible to imitate the way how tikz handles or are there some other convenient methods?

Comment: `shift={(1, 1)}` is parsed as "shift by 1*e_1 + 1*e_2", where e_1 and e_2 are the units vectors. This is different from`shift={(1cm, 1cm)}`, which produces a shift by 1cm in x direction and 1cm in y directions. In the default setting, e_1=(1cm,0) and e_2=(0,1cm), so both "accidentally" yield the same result.  It is really instructive to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/194703 for that. tikz also parses and interprets the coordinates in terms of some dimensions that specify their location in screen coordinates in pt.

Comment: The string that generates the coordinate is, in some situations, stored in `\csname tikz@dcl@coord@#1\endcsname`, where `#1` is the name of the coordinate. This happens if you use e.g. `\path (2,3,4) coordinate (A);`, then `\tikz@dcl@coord@A` is `(2,3,4)`. This has been used in https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools to allow Ti*k*Z to store 3D coordinates, and use them for vector operations.

Comment: Just what I want! And thanks for providing the link again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can disentangle what is going on at the low level.  First of all, `shift` is defined as

```
\tikzoption{shift}{\tikz@addtransform{\tikz@scan@one@point\pgftransformshift#1\relax}}%
```

The macro that does the heavy lifting scanning a point is `\tikz@scan@one@point`.  The result is a `\pgfpoint` which is then passed to `\pgftransformshift`.  This transformation is then added to the stack of transformations which is managed by `\tikz@addtransform`.

The procedure of `\tikz@scan@one@point` is a bit more tricky.  Here is a tree diagram of what happens inside approximately.

```
                         \tikz@scan@one@point
                                   |
                         if next character is +
                        /yes                 no\
                scan relative point             |
                       |                        |
             if next character is +             |
             /yes                no\            |
  relative to previous       relative to first  |
             \                     /            |
               scan absolute point --------------
                       |
                if character is (
               /yes            no\
              |           expand tokens (at most 100 times)
              |                  |
              |            valid coordinate found?
              |           /yes                  no\
              |          |                    Give up.
              |          |           "Cannot parse this coordinate"
              |          |
              -- if next character is [
                /yes                 no\
scan until ] and pass to \tikzset       |
               \                       /
                 if next character is $
                /yes                 no\
     <--- calc library                 |
                          if coordinate contains with cs:
                         /yes                          no\
                parse coordinate system                   |
                                          if coordinate contains intersection
                                         /yes                              no\
                                parse intersection              if coordinate contains with |
                                                               /yes                        no\
                                                    if coordinate contains -|                 |
                                                   /yes                    no\                |
                                          parse -| specifier      parse |- specifier          |
                                                                                              |
                                                                                   if coordinate contains :
                                                                                  /yes                   no\
                                                                        parse polar coordinate             |
                                                                                                if coordinate contains ,
                                                                                               /yes                   no\
                                                                                    parse regular coordinate     parse node name
```

In your case it will descend into the `parse regular coordinate` branch,  where the point will just be split at the comma and each component will be evaluated with `\pgfmathparse`.

Regarding the second part of your question:

> And if I want to define a pgfkey with a coordinate-like parameter so that when I pass a string like (2, 3, 4), it is parsed and the values are saved to three macros respectively, is it feasible to imitate the way how tikz handles or are there some other convenient methods?

In this case I think you are better off parsing this by hand, i.e. something along those lines:

```
\tikzset{
  triple/x/.store in=\triplex,
  triple/y/.store in=\tripley,
  triple/z/.store in=\triplez,
  triple/.style args={(#1,#2,#3)}{
    triple/x=#1,
    triple/y=#2,
    triple/z=#3,
  }
}

\tikzset{triple={(1,2,3)}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Just a side note: if you just want to parse a coordinate and obtain a `pgfpoint` without any transformation, you should do `\tikz@scan@one@point\pgf@process(#1)`, where `#1` is your coordinate (could be `1pt,2pt` or `mynode.north`).

Answer (score 3):

`shift={(1, 1)}` is parsed as

> shift by 1*e_1 + 1*e_2 ,

where e_1 and e_2 are the units vectors. This is different from `shift={(1cm, 1cm)}`, which produces a shift by 1cm in x direction and 1cm in y directions. In the default setting, `e_1=(1cm,0)` and `e_2=(0,1cm)`, so both "accidentally" yield the same result. It is really instructive to read this nice answer for that. Ti*k*Z also parses and interprets the coordinates in terms of some dimensions that specify their location in screen coordinates in pt.

Ti*k*Z does, under some circumstances, store the string that was used to define the coordinate. It works for the

```
\path (<coord>) coordinate (<A>);
```

syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2,3,4) coordinate (A) (5,1) coordinate (B);
\coordinate (C) at (5,4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
$(A)=\tikz@dcl@coord@A$

$(B)=\tikz@dcl@coord@B$

$(C)=\tikz@dcl@coord@C$
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

The example also shows that the syntax

```
\coordinate (C) at (5,4,3);
```

does not (yet?) work.

Comment: `\coordinate (C) at (5,4,3);` will never work with `\tikz@dcl@coord@C` because there is no way to reliably get the name `C` at the point where `(5,4,3)` is being scanned.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection there seems to be a problem in `\coordinate (C) at (5,4,3);`.  The point `(5,4,3)` is scanned and turned into a `\pgfpoint`, but that is then *scanned again* for no apparent reason.

Comment: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/785

Comment: I've found a workaround https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/785#issuecomment-554894073

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks!!!