# tikz arithmetic with numbers and lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths, tikz-calc

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\starty{3}
  \def\length{1};
  \coordinate(a1) at (1, \starty);
  \coordinate(b1) at ($(a1) + (0, -\length)$);
  \coordinate(a2) at (2, \starty - \length);
  \coordinate(b2) at ($(a2) + (0, \length)$);
  \draw[red, ->](a1) -- (b1);
  \draw[red, ->](b2) -- (a2);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (3, 0);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is 2 horizontally displaced arrows as it should be from a simple arithmetical inspection:

[image]

However, when I replace

```
  \def\length{1};
```

by

```
  \def\length{1cm};
```

the result is unexpected:

[image]

What is causing the discrepancy and how should I fix this example?

Comment: If you add `dimensionless+something with units`, `dimensionless` is interpreted in `pt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you add/combine expressions with and without units. Ti*k*Z distinguishes between expressions with and without units. I recommend reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/194703). If you have

```
 \path (x,y) coordinate (p);
```

with `x` and `y` dimensionless, then the point `p` will be at `x*(x unit vector)+y*(y unit vector)`. The initial values of these unit vectors are `(1cm,0)` and `(0,1cm)`, respectively, but you can change them, e.g. with `x=(1cm,0.2cm)`. (These changes are tricky if you do not supply units because if one uses `x={({cos(20)},{(sin(20)})},y={({cos(20+90)},{(sin(20+90)})}`, then one does not get just a rotated coordinate system. Rather, when `y=...` is parsed, it already uses the redefined `x unit vector`. This is why packages like `tikz-3dplot` attach units to define the rotated coordinate systems.)

If you have

```
 \path (x,y) coordinate (p);
```

where `x` and `y` carry units, then the point `p` will be at `x` to the right and `y` up (modulo transformations like rotations, of course). For the initial values of the unit vectors

```
 \path (1,2) coordinate (p);
```

and

```
 \path (1cm,2cm) coordinate (p);
```

yield the same results, but in general they don't. You can also have one coordinate with units and the other one without, e.g.

```
 \path (1cm,2) coordinate (p);
```

will lead to a point `1cm` to the right and shifted by twice the `y unit vector`.

Now, coming to your question, if you present Ti*k*Z a mix

```
 \path (a+b,y) coordinate (p);
```

where `a` carries units and `b` does not, then Ti*k*Z will attach units `pt` to `b`. So, for instance, in

```
 \path (1cm+1,2) coordinate (p);
```

`p` will have an `x` coordinate of `1cm+1pt`, while in

```
 \path (1+1,2) coordinate (p);
```

it will have an `x` coordinate of 2 times the `x unit vector`.

To illustrate this, I compare the coordinates of your MWE with those in which I appended `pt` to the dimensionless expressions, and show that they match.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{No units}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\starty{3}
  \def\length{1};
  \coordinate(a1) at (1, \starty);
  \coordinate(b1) at ($(a1) + (0, -\length)$);
  \coordinate(a2) at (2, \starty - \length);
  \coordinate(b2) at ($(a2) + (0, \length)$);
  \draw[red, ->](a1) -- (b1);
  \draw[red, ->](b2) -- (a2);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (3, 0);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Mix of expressions with and without units}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\starty{3}
  \def\length{1cm};
  \coordinate(a1) at (1, \starty);
  \coordinate(b1) at ($(a1) + (0, -\length)$);
  \coordinate(a2) at (2, \starty - \length);
  \coordinate(b2) at ($(a2) + (0, \length)$);
  \draw[red, ->](a1) -- (b1);
  \draw[red, ->](b2) -- (a2);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (3, 0);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
  \draw[<->,blue] (2,3pt-1cm) -- ++ (1,0) -- (2,3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]