# Tikz: What is the use of coordinate system xyz polar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I am learning TikZ from the manual—Till Tantau makes a great explanation job. However, I got stucked in the *Coordinate system xyz polar*. (See page 138 of [the tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)). The `canvas polar` coordinates make full sense to me, you define points in the plane through distance to coordinates origin and angle (see picture)

[image]

But for the `xyz polar` I do not understand the explanation in the manual and the examples make no sense to me.

Please, could I get some example that shows me what is the advantage of using them?

> Note added:

This comment [on page 139](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) makes it even more weird "[xy polar is] an alias for xyz polar, which some people might prefer as **there is no z-coordinate involved** in the xyz polar coordinates".

It seems quite an intricate coordinates system.

Comment: Not enough time for an answer, but I suppose this can be useful e.g if you want to mark specific points on an ellipse, maybe to explain stuff about conic sections or planetary movement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, okay, I imagine that must be a very rare case (!). If you could just give a graphic simple example it would a real understanding booster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is in the units. Let's have a look at the pgfmanual v3.1.5 on p. 138

[image]

The perhaps most important statement is the sentence

> Finally, multiply the resulting vector by the given radius factor.

Let's look at an example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw circle[x radius=2.5,y radius=1];
 \path (xyz polar cs:angle=50,x radius=2.5,y radius=1) 
    node[circle,fill=blue,inner sep=1.5pt]{}
 (canvas polar cs:angle=50,x radius=2.5,y radius=1) 
    node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt]{}
 (canvas polar cs:angle=50,x radius=2.5cm,y radius=1cm) 
    node[circle,draw=red,inner sep=1.75pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We did not specify the units in `xyz polar cs:` and the point is in on the ellipse as the coordinates here are *factors* that multiply the basis vectors. If we leave out the units in `canvas polar cs:`, they will be interpreted as dimensionful distances in pt, which is why the red dot is very close to the origin. If we add the units, we are back at the blue point.

The pgfmanual sort of admits that the name `xyz polar` may be confusing on p 139.

[image]

So just imagine we had talked about `xy polar` all time (but the question was specifically about `xyz polar`).

The same output as above is obtained with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm,y=1cm];
 \draw circle[radius=1];
 \path (xy polar cs:angle=50,radius=1) 
    node[circle,fill=blue,inner sep=1.5pt]{}
 (canvas polar cs:angle=50,radius=1)    
    node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt]{}
 (canvas polar cs:angle=50,x radius=2.5cm,y radius=1cm) 
    node[circle,draw=red,inner sep=1.75pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where you see that the advantage is that we only need to say `radius=1` in `xy polar cs`. The main reason why this is not really appreciated that much is that

```
\path (50:1) node[circle,fill=blue,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
```

yields the same blue point, and virtually everyone uses the last syntax. The parser checks whether the radius has dimensions via `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared`, and if not it interprets it as a factor. (I recommend reading [this very nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/194703) for a very pedagogical and clear discussion of radii with or without explicit units.)

The upshot is that probably most of us have at a given point used polar coordinates of the type `(<angle>:<radius factor>)`, where the term `radius factor` is used to indicate that we did not add dimensions to the radius. At this point we were using `xyz polar cs`, perhaps without explicitly noticing it. So `xyz polar cs` is in fact a very useful coordinate system which gets used a lot, perhaps without us users noticing that too much.

Finally, let us mention that `canvas polar` and `xyz polar` really are just wrappers for `\pgfpointpolar` and `\pgfpointpolarxy`, respectively.

```
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{canvas polar}
{%
  \tikzset{cs/.cd,angle=0,radius=0cm,#1}%
  \pgfpointpolar{\tikz@cs@angle}{\tikz@cs@xradius and \tikz@cs@yradius}%
}%

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{xyz polar}
{%
  \tikzset{cs/.cd,angle=0,radius=0,#1}%
  \pgfpointpolarxy{\tikz@cs@angle}{\tikz@cs@xradius and \tikz@cs@yradius}%
}%
```

where the latter can be looked up on p. 1084 and 1085, respectively

[image]

[image]

So, again, the difference is a radius vs. a radius factor.

> Edit

A further clarification is to see what happens when we change `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm,y=1cm]` in the example above to `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm];
    \draw circle[radius=1];
    \path (xy polar cs:angle=50,radius=1)
    node[circle,fill=blue,inner sep=1.5pt]{}
    (canvas polar cs:angle=50,radius=1)
    node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt]{}
    (canvas polar cs:angle=50,x radius=2.5cm,y radius=1cm)
    node[circle,draw=red,inner sep=1.75pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then we obtain following

[image]

The xyz polar coordinates adapt to the stretching of the x,y axes. As we see that the blue circle (in xyz polar) moves over the canvas to remain on the circle of radius 1, but the red perimeter remains away from the circle in the same canvas position.

Comment: Thanks! The best of all, the examples. It helped a lot.