How to connect ellipses in TikZ to match an isometric or flat view of a cylinder
I originally asked this question on stack overflow, however I got redirected here.
I'm using Tikz to create an isometric view of a cylinder. The flat bases of the cylinder may be angled 45° around the y axis. I now need to connect these bases with straight lines to render a cylinder. For example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, z = {(-0.866cm, -0.5cm)}] %isometric
        %coordinate system
        \draw[color = red] (0, 0, 0) -- ++(0, 0, 1);
        \draw[color = blue] (0, 0, 0) -- ++(0, 1, 0);
        \draw (0, 0, 0) -- ++(1, 0, 0);

        %Useful Parameters
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radff}{0.2/sqrt(2)}

        
        \draw (-2,0,-2) circle[x = {(1, 0, 0)}, y = {(0, 1, 0)}, radius=0.2];
        \draw[dashed] (-2,0,0) circle[x = {(1, 0, 0)}, y = {(0, 1, 0)}, radius=0.2];

        \draw (-2+\radff, -\radff, -2) -- ++(0, 0, 3.8);
        \draw (-2-\radff, +\radff, -2) -- ++(0, 0, 4.2);

        \draw (-2,0,+2) circle[x = {(1, 0, -1)}, y = {(0, 1, 0)}, radius=0.2];
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Now when I switch to a flat view this obviously does not work, as the edges to not properly connect to the circles.
\begin{scope}[x={(0cm,0cm)}, z = {(1cm, 0cm)}] %left
...
\end{scope}


The circles here are rendered correctly, however the connections do not work.
Is there a good way to calculate the angle or the offset of the starting point of those connecting lines in 3d space? Additionally I need to calculate the change in length of those connections. I can assume that the cylinder is aligned with one of the
Unfortunately I have rather poor spacial comprehension and have trouble visualizing the lengths and angles I need to calculate. Answers containing an implementation using pgfmath would be greatly appreciated.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Linked the posts to each other. Good advice, thank you!

Thanks for adding the links!

Possibly relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31548/86

For the regular circles:
You find the dot product of its parametric formula with the screen normal vector. [Since it is isometric projection, it is (1,1,1).] E.g.,
.2cos(t)*1 + .2sin(t)*1 + 0*1 = 0 ---> cos(t)=-sin(t) ---> t=-45,135
So we base the lines coordinates on that.
For the oblique circle:
We do the same thing, except we add - in this case, it depends on the vectors used - the amount it is distorted by, multiplied by its height:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}
        ,z = {(-0.866cm, -0.5cm)}
    ] %isometric

        %coordinate system
        \draw[color = red] (0, 0, 0) -- ++(0, 0, 1);
        \draw[color = blue] (0, 0, 0) -- ++(0, 1, 0);
        \draw (0, 0, 0) -- ++(1, 0, 0);

        %Useful Parameters
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radff}{0.2/sqrt(2)}

        \draw (-2,0,-2) circle[x = {(1, 0, 0)}, y = {(0, 1, 0)}, radius=0.2];
        \draw[dashed] (-2,0,0) circle[x = {(1, 0, 0)}, y = {(0, 1, 0)}, radius=0.2];
        \draw (-2,0,+2) circle[x = {(1, 0, -1)}, y = {(0, 1, 0)}, radius=0.2];

        %\draw (-2+\radff, -\radff, -2) -- ++(0, 0, 3.8);
        %\draw (-2-\radff, +\radff, -2) -- ++(0, 0, 4.2);
        \draw ({-2+0.2*cos(-45)},{0+0.2*sin(-45)},-2) -- ({-2+0.2*cos(-45)},{0+0.2*sin(-45)},{+2-.2*cos(-45)});
        \draw ({-2+0.2*cos(-45+180)},{0+0.2*sin(-45+180)},-2) -- ({-2+0.2*cos(-45+180)},{0+0.2*sin(-45+180)},{+2-.2*cos(-45+180)});
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



is there any way to automatically get the screen normal vector?

@DavidK. It's isometric, so its easy!, (1,1,1)

@DavidK. This post shows how to do it in other perspectives: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729510/319072
